# setImmediate vs. nextTick

Tags: javascript, node.js, setimmediate

Node.js version 0.10 was released today and introduced  `setImmediate`. The [API changes](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.8-and-v0.10) documentation suggests using it when doing recursive `nextTick` calls.

From what [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) it seems very similar to `process.nextTick`.

When should I use `nextTick` and when should I use `setImmediate`?

Comment: There are 5 paragraphs about this change on the blog http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/03/11/node-v0-10-0-stable/

Comment: From performance benchmarks it looks like `nextTick` is faster than `setImmediate` on large calculations.

Comment: For the record, I read those five paragraphs first and still ended up on this question when it didn't really clear anything up for me. The accepted answer is much more concise and actually describes what `setImmediate` does in better detail.

Comment: I've explained the difference in great detail in my [blog](http://plafer.github.io/2015/09/08/nextTick-vs-setImmediate/).

Comment: Is it the case that GC can run before `setImmediate`, but not before `nextTick`?

Comment: That is a separate question but no - GC can run whenever GC wants to run. It is true that setImmediate gives GC a more appropriate opportunity to run over a clearer scope (an external event) but Node doesn't manually pause GC for other code. You can always run GC yourself with --expose-gc by the way or trace GCs and see :)

Answer (score 564, accepted):

Use `setImmediate` if you want to queue the function behind whatever I/O event callbacks that are already in the event queue.  Use `process.nextTick` to effectively queue the function at the head of the event queue so that it executes immediately after the current function completes.

So in a case where you're trying to break up a long running, CPU-bound job using recursion, you would now want to use `setImmediate` rather than `process.nextTick` to queue the next iteration as otherwise any I/O event callbacks wouldn't get the chance to run between iterations.

Comment: Why would I not use process.nextTick all the time then? Hope you will answer, all this nextTick is confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Callbacks passed to process.nextTick will usually be called at the end of the current flow of execution, and are thus approximately as fast as calling a function synchronously. Left unchecked, this would starve the event loop, preventing any I/O from occurring. setImmediates are queued in the order created, and are popped off the queue once per loop iteration. This is different from process.nextTick which will execute process.maxTickDepth queued callbacks per iteration. setImmediate will yield to the event loop after firing a queued callback to make sure I/O is not being starved.

Comment: In the browser world, setTimeout(func, 0) works as process.nextTick() but there is no equivalent for setImmediate(). I was however told that the behavior of process.nextTick() has changed, has it?

Comment: @UstamanSangat `setImmediate` is a part of the DOM API and some browsers already support it. `nextTick` will now throw a warning if it thinks it is inappropriately used (try to split in recursion in it and see!)

Comment: @UstamanSangat setImmediate is supported by IE10+ only, all other browsers are stubbornly refusing to implement the likely future standard because they don't like being beaten by Microsoft. To achieve a similar result in FF/Chrome, you can use postMessage (post a message to your own window). You could consider using requestAnimationFrame as well, especially if your updates are UI-related. setTimeout(func, 0) does not work like process.nextTick at all.

Comment: @fabspro "because they don't like being beaten my Microsoft" makes you sound sore about something. It's mostly because it's terribly, terribly named. If there's one time setImmediate function will never, ever run, it's immediately. The name of the function is the exact opposite of what it does. nextTick and setImmediate would be better off switching around; setImmediate executes immediately after the current stack completes (before waiting I/O) and nextTick executes at he end of the next tick (after waiting I/O). But then, this has been said a thousand times already.

Comment: @CraigAndrews You said it yourself. "setImmediate executes immediately after the current stack completes". It sets a function to be called back immediately, when control is returned from the currently running script. I dare you to think of a simpler and equally memorable name for it.

Comment: @fabspro But unfortunately the function is called nextTick. nextTick executes "immediately" while setImmediate is more like a setTimeout/postMessage.

Comment: @Robert Well, if nextTick was available in web browsers it would make sense to have a pair of functions named nextTick and laterTick, or as you suggest, setImmediate and setLater or something. But nextTick is not relevant to web browsers today, because it is not available. What names would you propose?

Comment: @CraigAndrews I would avoid `requestAnimationFrame` because it doesn't always occur (I have definitely seen this, I think example was tab wasn't current tab) and it can get called before the page has completed painting (i.e. browser is still busy drawing).

Comment: JohnnyHK said: "Use setImmediate if you want to queue the function behind whatever I/O event callbacks that are already in the event queue."
Craig Andrews said: "setImmediate executes immediately after the current stack completes (before waiting I/O)"  I thought setImmediate is supposed to be used in recursive calls "to avoid pre-empting the I/O event loop for long-running jobs." (i.e.  AFTER waiting I/O)  Was that a typo from Craig?

Comment: @zipzit I think Craig Andrews was talking about how the functions would make a lot more sense *if* the names were swapped.

Comment: just shim it if you *really* need it. `window.setImmediate = window.setImmediate || function(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 10); };`

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is a hack and IE does not seem to be able to handle a lot of `requestAnimationFrame` operations at once (Chrome and Firefox don't appear to suffer from the same issues)

Comment: It should be noted that `setImmediate` exits the active domain, `process.nextTick` does not. I'm fully aware that node domains are "deprecated" (and almost comically so).

Comment: @Tracker1 That is not a proper shim for setImmediate. They might as well just use setTimeout(fn, 10) directly. Misses the point of setImmediate completely.

Answer (score 108):

As an illustration:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import http from 'http';
    
const options = {
  host: 'www.stackoverflow.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html'
};

describe('deferredExecution', () => {
  it('deferredExecution', (done) => {
    console.log('Start');
    setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout 1'), 0);
    setImmediate(() => console.log('setImmediate 1'));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log('nextTick 1'));
    setImmediate(() => console.log('setImmediate 2'));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log('nextTick 2'));
    http.get(options, () => console.log('network IO'));
    fs.readdir(process.cwd(), () => console.log('file system IO 1'));
    setImmediate(() => console.log('setImmediate 3'));
    process.nextTick(() => console.log('nextTick 3'));
    setImmediate(() => console.log('setImmediate 4'));
    fs.readdir(process.cwd(), () => console.log('file system IO 2'));
    console.log('End');
    setTimeout(done, 1500);
  });
});
```

will give the following output

```
Start // synchronous
End // synchronous
nextTick 1 // microtask
nextTick 2 // microtask
nextTick 3 // microtask
setTimeout 1 // macrotask
file system IO 1 // macrotask
file system IO 2 // macrotask
setImmediate 1 // macrotask
setImmediate 2 // macrotask
setImmediate 3 // macrotask
setImmediate 4 // macrotask
network IO // macrotask
```

I hope this can help to understand the difference.

Updated:

> Callbacks deferred with `process.nextTick()` run before any other I/O
> event is fired, while with setImmediate(), the execution is queued
> behind any I/O event that is already in the queue.
>
> **Node.js Design Patterns**, by Mario Casciaro (probably the best book about node.js/js)

Comment: I think it's important to point out that setTimeout() and setImmediate() when not within an I/O cycle the order is non-deterministic depending on the performance of a process. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/
`For example, if we run the following script which is not within an I/O cycle (i.e. the main module), the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of the process:`

So, this answer doesn't really answer the exact difference but merely an example that could vary in different context

Comment: As pointed out by @Actung. it is very important to know whether setTimetout and setImmediate are within an I/O cycle or not, to determine the outcome.

Comment: Why is I01 at the very end?

Answer (score 76):

I think I can illustrate this quite nicely. Since `nextTick` is called at the end of the current operation, calling it recursively can end up blocking the event loop from continuing. `setImmediate` solves this by firing in the check phase of the event loop, allowing event loop to continue normally.

```
   ┌───────────────────────┐
┌─>│        timers         │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
│  │     I/O callbacks     │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
│  │     idle, prepare     │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘      ┌───────────────┐
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐      │   incoming:   │
│  │         poll          │<─────┤  connections, │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘      │   data, etc.  │
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐      └───────────────┘
│  │        check          │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
└──┤    close callbacks    │
   └───────────────────────┘
```

source: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Notice that the check phase is immediately after the poll phase. This is because the poll phase and I/O callbacks are the most likely places your calls to `setImmediate` are going to run. So ideally most of those calls will actually be pretty immediate, just not as immediate as `nextTick` which is checked after every operation and technically exists outside of the event loop.

Let's take a look at a little example of the difference between `setImmediate` and `process.nextTick`:

```
function step(iteration) {
  if (iteration === 10) return;
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log(`setImmediate iteration: ${iteration}`);
    step(iteration + 1); // Recursive call from setImmediate handler.
  });
  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log(`nextTick iteration: ${iteration}`);
  });
}
step(0);
```

Let's say we just ran this program and are stepping through the first iteration of the event loop. It will call into the `step` function with iteration zero. It will then register two handlers, one for `setImmediate` and one for `process.nextTick`. We then recursively call this function from the `setImmediate` handler which will run in the next check phase. The `nextTick` handler will run at the end of the current operation interrupting the event loop, so even though it was registered second it will actually run first.

The order ends up being: `nextTick` fires as current operation ends, next event loop begins, normal event loop phases execute, `setImmediate` fires and recursively calls our `step` function to start the process all over again. Current operation ends, `nextTick` fires, etc.

The output of the above code would be:

```
nextTick iteration: 0
setImmediate iteration: 0
nextTick iteration: 1
setImmediate iteration: 1
nextTick iteration: 2
setImmediate iteration: 2
nextTick iteration: 3
setImmediate iteration: 3
nextTick iteration: 4
setImmediate iteration: 4
nextTick iteration: 5
setImmediate iteration: 5
nextTick iteration: 6
setImmediate iteration: 6
nextTick iteration: 7
setImmediate iteration: 7
nextTick iteration: 8
setImmediate iteration: 8
nextTick iteration: 9
setImmediate iteration: 9
```

Now let's move our recursive call to `step` into our `nextTick` handler instead of the `setImmediate`.

```
function step(iteration) {
  if (iteration === 10) return;
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log(`setImmediate iteration: ${iteration}`);
  });
  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log(`nextTick iteration: ${iteration}`);
    step(iteration + 1); // Recursive call from nextTick handler.
  });
}
step(0);
```

Now that we have moved the recursive call to `step` into the `nextTick` handler things will behave in a different order. Our first iteration of the event loop runs and calls `step` registering a `setImmedaite` handler as well as a `nextTick` handler. After the current operation ends our `nextTick` handler fires which recursively calls `step` and registers another `setImmediate` handler as well as another `nextTick` handler. Since a `nextTick` handler fires after the current operation, registering a `nextTick` handler within a `nextTick` handler will cause the second handler to run immediately after the current handler operation finishes. The `nextTick` handlers will keep firing, preventing the current event loop from ever continuing. We will get through all our `nextTick` handlers before we see a single `setImmediate` handler fire.

The output of the above code ends up being:

```
nextTick iteration: 0
nextTick iteration: 1
nextTick iteration: 2
nextTick iteration: 3
nextTick iteration: 4
nextTick iteration: 5
nextTick iteration: 6
nextTick iteration: 7
nextTick iteration: 8
nextTick iteration: 9
setImmediate iteration: 0
setImmediate iteration: 1
setImmediate iteration: 2
setImmediate iteration: 3
setImmediate iteration: 4
setImmediate iteration: 5
setImmediate iteration: 6
setImmediate iteration: 7
setImmediate iteration: 8
setImmediate iteration: 9
```

Note that had we not interrupted the recursive call and aborted it after 10 iterations then the `nextTick` calls would keep recursing and never letting the event loop continue to the next phase. This is how `nextTick` can become blocking when used recursively whereas `setImmediate` will fire in the next event loop and setting another `setImmediate` handler from within one won't interrupt the current event loop at all, allowing it to continue executing phases of the event loop as normal.

PS - I agree with other commenters that the names of the two functions could easily be swapped since `nextTick` sounds like it's going to fire in the next event loop rather than the end of the current one, and the end of the current loop is more "immediate" than the beginning of the next loop. Oh well, that's what we get as an API matures and people come to depend on existing interfaces.

Comment: it is important to reiterate Node's warning about the use of process.nextTick. If you enqueue a large number of callbacks in the nextTickQueue, you can potentially starve the event loop by ensuring the poll phase is never reached. This is reason why you should generally prefer setImmediate.

Answer (score 32):

In the comments in the answer, it does not explicitly state that nextTick shifted from Macrosemantics to Microsemantics.

before node 0.9 (when setImmediate was introduced), nextTick operated at the start of the next callstack.

since node 0.9, nextTick operates at the end of the existing callstack, whereas setImmediate is at the start of the next callstack

check out https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate for tools and details

Answer (score 16):

Some great answers here detailing how they both work.

Just adding one that answers the specific question asked:

> When should I use `nextTick` and when should I use `setImmediate`?

---

### Always use `setImmediate`.

---

The [Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and `process.nextTick()`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick-vs-setimmediate) doc includes the following:

> *We recommend developers use `setImmediate()` in all cases because it's easier to reason about (and it leads to code that's compatible with a wider variety of environments, like browser JS.)*

---

Earlier in the doc it warns that `process.nextTick` can lead to...

> some bad situations because **it allows you to "starve" your I/O by making recursive `process.nextTick()` calls**, which prevents the event loop from reaching the **poll** phase.

As it turns out, `process.nextTick` can even starve `Promises`:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => { console.log('this happens LAST'); });

process.nextTick(() => {
  console.log('all of these...');
  process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log('...happen before...');
    process.nextTick(() => {
      console.log('...the Promise ever...');
      process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('...has a chance to resolve');
      })
    })
  })
})
```

On the other hand, `setImmediate` is "*easier to reason about*" and avoids these types of issues:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => { console.log('this happens FIRST'); });

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log('this happens LAST');
})
```

---

So unless there is a specific need for the unique behavior of `process.nextTick`, the recommended approach is to "*use `setImmediate()` in all cases*".

Answer (score 11):

In simple terms, process.NextTick() would executed at next tick of event loop. However, the setImmediate, basically has a separate phase which ensures that the callback registered under setImmediate() will be called only after the IO callback and polling phase.

Please refer to this link for nice explanation:
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c

[image: simplified event loop events]

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to check [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) section dedicated for Loop to get better understanding. Some snippet taken from there:

We have two calls that are similar as far as users are concerned, but their names are confusing.

- process.nextTick() fires immediately on the same phase
- setImmediate() fires on the following iteration or 'tick' of the
  event loop

In essence, the names should be swapped. process.nextTick() fires more immediately than setImmediate(), but this is an artifact of the past which is unlikely to change.

Answer (score 2):

### You should never break up CPU-heavy operation using `process.nextTick()`

> You should never break up such work using process.nextTick(). Doing so will lead to a microtask queue that never empties—your application will be trapped in the same phase forever!
> -- [Thomas Hunter. Distributed Systems with Node.js](https://www.booktopia.com.au/distributed-systems-with-node-js-thomas-hunter-ii/ebook/9781492077244.html)

**Each phase of event loop contains several callback:**

[image: One phase of loop event]

Once `process.nextTick()` fired, it will always stay in same phase.

#### Example

```
const nt_recursive = () => process.nextTick(nt_recursive);
nt_recursive(); // setInterval will never run

const si_recursive = () => setImmediate(si_recursive);
si_recursive(); // setInterval will run

setInterval(() => console.log('hi'), 10);
```

In this example, the `setInterval()` represents some asynchronous work that the application performs, such as responding to incoming HTTP requests.

Once the `nt_recursive()` function is run, the application ends up with a microtask queue that never empties and the asynchronous work never gets processed.

But the alternative version `si_recursive()` does not have the same side effect.

Making `setImmediate()` calls within a check phase adds callbacks to the *next* event loop iteration’s check phase queue, not the current phase’s queue.

### Case might use `process.nextTick`

Make function process all asynchronously.

```
function foo(count, callback) {
  if (count <= 0) {
    return process.nextTick(() => callback(new TypeError('count > 0')));
  }
  myAsyncOperation(count, callback);
}
```

> -- [Thomas Hunter. Distributed Systems with Node.js](https://www.booktopia.com.au/distributed-systems-with-node-js-thomas-hunter-ii/ebook/9781492077244.html)

In this case, either using `setImmediate()` or `process.nextTick()` is okay; just make sure you don’t accidentally introduce recursion.