# Should I use process.nextTick or setImmediate for asynchronous iteration?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

I'm working on [a JavaScript library](http://dtao.github.io/lazy.js/) that provides, among other things, map/reduce functions on sequences that can be iterated asynchronously.

A [helpful soul on GitHub](https://github.com/dtao/lazy.js/issues/6) suggested that for Node.js, I should use `process.nextTick` to make asynchronous iterations as fast as possible. (The library currently uses `setTimeout` in all environments, which I do understand is suboptimal.) I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to Node, so I was reading up on how this method works and it isn't clear to me whether it's a good choice or not.

According to [the answer to another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick), it seems that it would probably make more sense to use `setImmediate` in this case as `nextTick` apparently jumps *ahead* of pending I/O events, which seems bad to me.

This appears to be corroborated by some remarks in [the official Node v0.10.0 announcment](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/03/11/node-v0-10-0-stable/):

> In v0.10, `nextTick` handlers are run right after each call from C++
>   into JavaScript. That means that, if your JavaScript code calls
>   `process.nextTick`, then the callback will fire as soon as the code runs
>   to completion, but *before* going back to the event loop.

So am I right, and iterating over sequences asynchronously should be done with `setImmediate`? Or would `nextTick` be a better choice here? (In either case, a clear explanation *why* would be much appreciated.)

Comment: Why exactly do you need "asynchronous iteration"?

Comment: suppose you have a long list of data items that needs to get some kind of expensive processing applied, item by item. using `nextTick`/ `setImmediate` will allow other code to run in between each processing step, thus potentially preserving the capability to e.g. response to a HTTP request or, say, user interaction with the GUI.

Answer (score 10):

Some considerations:

I'd first do serious benchmarks to what extend setImmediate is slower than `process.nextTick`. If it's not (much) slower, I'd go for `setImmediate` straight away since that won't starve the event loop.

In node 0.10 there's a hard limit (1000, see [node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_maxtickdepth)) to how many times you can recursively call nextTick, so you should prevent that from happening in any case. You either need to choose a strategy before iteration, or be able to change strategy during iteration (while checking for current iteration count).

If you choose process.nextTick for performance reasons, you might want to set a configurable hard limit for how many times it would do `process.nextTick` in a row, and else switch to `setImmediate`. I don't have experience with serious work loads on nodejs, but I do think people are not gonna like it if your library makes their I/O choppy.

setImmediate would certainly be safest, all in all.

As for the browser:
I haven't studied your library, but since you are actually coming from `setTimeout`, you may be helped learning about the new breed of delay techniques via `window.postMessage` and what not. There's a nice and small library called [next-tick](https://github.com/timoxley/next-tick) (but with different semantics than node next-tick!) and there's a [cross-browser shim for setImmediate](https://github.com/NobleJS/setImmediate), which is quite a bit heavier because 1) it needs to implement the setImmediate spec (including ability to cancel scheduled tasks) and 2) it has much wider browser compatibility.

Check out this [async sorting demo](http://jphpsf.github.io/setImmediate-shim-demo/) comparing setImmediate (shim) to setTimeout.

Comment: Even if `nextTick` was considerably faster than `setImmediate` in some way, I think he'd be better off just executing more of the work before calling `setImmediate` again. In the end, there's no point in marshalling code execution if it'll end up blocking everything anyway.

Comment: @HristoDachev: Good point. But with his question as it stands, it isn't exactly clear why he wants to "asynchronously iterate". Dividing the work into batches which are executed synchronously would lose some of  the asynchronousness. If all that's needed is a asynchronous interface for a batch operation, than a single `setImmediate` for the whole amount of work would suffice, making speed differences irrelevant. I'll ask.