# nextTick vs setImmediate, visual explanation

Tags: node.js

I'm very confused about the differences between nextTick and setImmediate. I've read all the documentation about them on the internet but I still don't understand how they work.

Examples:

```
function log(n) { console.log(n); }
```

**setImmediate**

```
setImmediate(function() {
  setImmediate(function() {
    log(1);
    setImmediate(function() { log(2); });
    setImmediate(function() { log(3); });
  });
  setImmediate(function() {
    log(4);
    setImmediate(function() { log(5); });
    setImmediate(function() { log(6); });
  });
});

//1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**nextTick**

```
process.nextTick(function() {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    log(1);
    process.nextTick(function() { log(2); });
    process.nextTick(function() { log(3); });
  });
  process.nextTick(function() {
    log(4);
    process.nextTick(function() { log(5); });
    process.nextTick(function() { log(6); });
  });
});

//1 4 2 3 5 6
```

Why these results? Please explain with a visual or very easy to follow explanation. Even the node core devs don't agree at how nextTick and setImmediate should be understood by people.

Sources:

- [setImmediate vs. nextTick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick)
- [Why is setImmediate much more slower than nextTick?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/A_uo0Mfmk5o)
- [setImmediate is not always very immediate](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5798)

Comment: The output is the same (```1 4 2 3 5 6```) for both executions (Node v5.6.0)

Comment: both produces same output

Comment: Look at the year, 5 years ago! Lots of things could have changed.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Consider the following two examples:

**setImmediate**

```
setImmediate(function A() {
  setImmediate(function B() {
    log(1);
    setImmediate(function D() { log(2); });
    setImmediate(function E() { log(3); });
  });
  setImmediate(function C() {
    log(4);
    setImmediate(function F() { log(5); });
    setImmediate(function G() { log(6); });
  });
});

setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log('TIMEOUT FIRED');
}, 0)

// 'TIMEOUT FIRED' 1 4 2 3 5 6
// OR
// 1 'TIMEOUT FIRED' 4 2 3 5 6
```

**nextTick**

```
process.nextTick(function A() {
  process.nextTick(function B() {
    log(1);
    process.nextTick(function D() { log(2); });
    process.nextTick(function E() { log(3); });
  });
  process.nextTick(function C() {
    log(4);
    process.nextTick(function F() { log(5); });
    process.nextTick(function G() { log(6); });
  });
});

setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log('TIMEOUT FIRED');
}, 0)

// 1 4 2 3 5 6 'TIMEOUT FIRED'
```

setImmediate callbacks are fired off the event loop, once per iteration in the order that they were queued. So on the first iteration of the event loop, callback A is fired. Then on the second iteration of the event loop, callback B is fired, then on the third iteration of the event loop callback C is fired, etc. This prevents the event loop from being blocked and allows other I/O or timer callbacks to be called in the mean time (as is the case of the 0ms timeout, which is fired on the 1st or 2nd loop iteration).

nextTick callbacks, however, are always fired immediately after the current code is done executing and BEFORE going back to the event loop. In the nextTick example, we end up executing all the nextTick callbacks before ever returning to the event loop. Since setTimeout's callback will be called from the event loop, the text 'TIMEOUT FIRED' will not be output until we're done with every nextTick callback.

Comment: Perfect, the last paragraph is the key to understand the main difference.

Comment: your nextTick example has different output: `TIMEOUT FIRED 1 4 2 3 5 6`

Comment: What version of node are you running? On node 0.10.x you should always have your nextTick callbacks run before hitting the event loop.

Comment: I wish they would have chosen a different name. Right now "nextTick" is more immediate than setImmediate.

Comment: Do you have an example with relation to I/O?

Comment: frankly if process.nextTick doesn't go back out to the event loop then wtf is the point of it. If I wanted to call a function next I would just call it explicitly by name. No wonder, process.nextTick is being deprecated. I always thought process.nextTick functioned like setImmediate actually does. process.nextTick is then a huge misnomer.

Comment: I'm know what you mean. There's an example in the docs that explains a possible use case. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback

Comment: @DaveStibrany .. sorry to bug you after a long time . I am a newbie to node.js. Just to clarify why A, then B,then C,then D and E and then F and G callbacks were called in order ? Why not A,B,D,E,C,F,G ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder Because when A executes, it sets B and C to be scheduled next. When B executes it sets D and E to be scheduled next, but C has already been scheduled for after B. Remember that there is a difference between when the callback is scheduled or registered and when the callback actually fires.

Comment: @DaveStibrany in `setImmediate `  I think B and C are pushed to  `check queue` in same iteration because JS is `run to complete`

Comment: Yes  **@Guichi** You are absolutely right. B and C scheduled at the time of A() Callaback execution.

Answer (score 25):

According the Node.js doc names of these two function are [exactly swapped](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/the-event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md#processnexttick-vs-setimmediate)

**setImmediate() (*BEST RECOMMENDED*)**

*It's fire first at event queue*

---

**process.nextTick() (*USE FOR SPECIAL CASES see example later on*)**

It's fire immediately, It's kinda write an statement more at the end at the current file

---

If we have this code

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('Hello world 5'); // It's waiting like a normal person at a queue
}, 0);

setImmediate(function(){
  console.log('Hello world 4'); 
  // It's like get to last and be take care of first 
  // but always after of .nextTick and before of setInterval(, 0)
});

process.nextTick(function(){
   console.log('Hello world 3'); // It's like be at the bottom at this file
});

console.log('Hello world 1');
console.log('Hello world 2');
```

A visual explanation as per your request:

[image]

Cases for use process.nextTick() when you have to emit and event before to handled it:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const util = require('util');

function MyEmitter() {
  EventEmitter.call(this);

  // use nextTick to emit the event once a handler is assigned
  process.nextTick(function () {
    this.emit('event');
  }.bind(this));
}
util.inherits(MyEmitter, EventEmitter);

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', function() {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});
```

Look at this vide where [Philip Roberts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) give us a great explanation about runtime event loop and look at this online eventloop debugger [Live test how event loop works](http://latentflip.com/loupe/)

Source:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/the-event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md#processnexttick-vs-setimmediate

Comment: if you run the first snippet, it does not behave as you mentioned -

Hello world 1
Hello world 2
Hello world 3
Hello world 5
Hello world 4

Answer (score 8):

I can't reproduce your results for `setImmediate`. It should be the same as `nextTick` (and it is in my tests) since in this situation they do pretty much the same thing. The only reasonable explanation for that is that `setImmediate` is somehow synchronous, but it is not.

And according to [NodeJS documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) the only real difference is that multiple `nextTick` may fire in one loop iteration (depending on `maxTickDepth`), while `setImmediate` fires once per iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Below gives you better clarity.

### [setImmediate](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args)

1. It's execute a script once the current poll phase completes.
2. It's a timer module function and timer functions are global, you can call them without `require`.
3. It can cleared by clearImmediate().
4. Set "immediate" execution of the callback after I/O events' callbacks before setTimeout() and setInterval().

### [nextTick](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args)

1. It's a process global object function of NodeJS.
2. All callbacks passed to process.nextTick() will be resolved before the event loop continues.
3. Allow users to handle errors.
4. Helps to try the request again before the event loop continues.

#### Simple code Snippet.

```
console.log("I'm First");

setImmediate(function () {
  console.log('Im setImmediate');
});

console.log("I'm Second");

process.nextTick(function () {
  console.log('Im nextTick');
});

console.log("I'm Last");

/*
Output
$ node server.js
I'm First
I'm Second
I'm Last
Im nextTick
Im setImmediate
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all the answers above are obsolete, because I got different answers constantly with the current version of nodejs and it is easy to reason about

```
var log=console.log
log(process.version)

var makeAsyncCall
if(false)
    makeAsyncCall=setImmediate
else
    makeAsyncCall=process.nextTick;

makeAsyncCall(function A () {
    makeAsyncCall(function B() {
        log(1);
        makeAsyncCall(function C() { log(2); });
        makeAsyncCall(function D() { log(3); });
    });
    makeAsyncCall(function E() {
        log(4);
        makeAsyncCall(function F() { log(5); });
        makeAsyncCall(function G() { log(6); });
    });
});
//1
//4
//2
//3
//5
//6
//in both case
```

After reading https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/the-event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md#processnexttick-vs-setimmediate 
let use start from `setImmediate` we should keep track of the `check queue` because it is where the `setImmediate` callback reside.

**First iteration**

`A` is push to `check queue`

check queue :[A]

**Second iteration**

`A` is pull out from `queue` to execute

During its execution ,it put `B` and `E` to `queue`and then, `A` complete and start next iteration

check queue :[B,E]

**Third iteration**

pull out `B` and push `C` `D`

check queue :[E,C,D]

**Forth iteration**

pull out `E` and push `F` `G`

check queue : [C,D,F,G]

**Finally**

execute the callbacks in the queue sequentially

For `nextTick` case, the queue works exactly the same way,that is why it produce same result

The different is that :

> the nextTickQueue will be processed after the current operation
>   completes, regardless of the current phase of the event loop

To be clear,the event loop maintain multiple queues and `check queue` is just one of them,the node will decide which queue to use based on some rules

with `process.nextTick` however,it is sort of bypassing all the rule and execute the callback in `nextTick` immediately