# Hitting Maximum call stack exceeded in Lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a nodejs lambda function which essentially runs a set of tests in newman (A JS library of Postman). The tests run successfully but when the lambda is trying to send back a message to Codepipeline using codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult, it keeps throwing the maximum call stack exceeded error. The printed error stack doesn't seem to be very long (I can just see 6 lines printed).

Any help with how why the stack trace is exceeding and how it could be debugged easily would help.

Relevant exports.handler

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var jobId = event["CodePipeline.job"].id;
    console.log("Triggering tests for job "+ jobId);


    var putJobSuccess = function(message) {
        codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult({jobId: jobId}, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                context.fail(err);
            } else {
                context.succeed(message)
            }
        });
    }

    var putJobFailure = function(message) {
        console.log("Tests failed for job: " + jobId);
        var params = {
            jobId: jobId,
            failureDetails: {
                message: JSON.stringify(message),
                type: 'JobFailed',
              externalExecutionId: ""
            }
        }
    }

    var testRunnerCallback = function(response) {
        if (response === 1) {
            putJobFailure("Tests failed. View logs for details");
        } else {
            putJobSuccess("All Tests passed");
        }
    }

    Newman.execute(collections, newmanOptions, testRunnerCallback);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936486/node-js-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Comment: Tried those approaches. But of no avail unfortunately.

Comment: please paste your code here, so we can help

Comment: Added to the original question

Answer (score -1):

The `context` has no `success` or `fail` method. Use the `callback` parameter.

Try this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var jobId = event["CodePipeline.job"].id;
    console.log("Triggering tests for job "+ jobId);


    var putJobSuccess = function(message) {
        codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult({jobId: jobId}, callback);
    }

    var putJobFailure = function(message) {
        console.log("Tests failed for job: " + jobId);
        var params = {
            jobId: jobId,
            failureDetails: {
                message: JSON.stringify(message),
                type: 'JobFailed',
              externalExecutionId: ""
            }
        }
        callback(params);
    }

    var testRunnerCallback = function(response) {
        if (response === 1) {
            putJobFailure("Tests failed. View logs for details");
        } else {
            putJobSuccess("All Tests passed");
        }
    }

    Newman.execute(collections, newmanOptions, testRunnerCallback);
}
```

Comment: The context object *does* have success and fail methods. Not sure where you're getting your information.

Comment: Yup it does have the success and fail methods. In either case though the codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult keeps exceeding stack size

Comment: @idbehold I have checked the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html), and logged out context object by running lambda, what did I miss??

Comment: @eenagy see [their docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html#nodejs-prog-model-oldruntime-context-methods): "The context object supports the done(), succeed(), and fail() methods that you can use to terminate your Lambda function. **These methods are also present in runtime v4.3 for backward compatibility.**"