# recursive stack error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, recursion

trying to search specific value in a nested json object by using recursive code , and this error occurred:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What I tried so far:

```
    exports.indexOfJson = function(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]) {
            if (findNestedValue(array[i], value)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
};


function findNestedValue(obj, value) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
                if (findNestedValue(obj[k], value))
                    return true;
        } else {
            if (obj[k] && obj[k].toString() === value.toString()){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: please a have look..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: it works when array.length not too large. please show json sample.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20999077/6121703 Try add `process.nextTick` or `setImmediate` in `findNestedValue`.