# Maximum call stack size exceeded in sailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am getting following error when I run my sails app, I am using `sails 0.12.11 node v.5.6.0`, we do have branch call `next`, In the app we are  populating initial data to the DB, I could not figure out what causes this error, someone could help me to short this out.

```
events.js:110
    handler.call(self, arg1, arg2, arg3);
            ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at emitThree (events.js:110:13)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Walker._wPostFilesHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:133:10)
    at Walker._wReadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:152:10)
    at Walker._wReaddirHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:169:10)
    at Walker._wWalkSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:238:8)
    at Walker._wNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:263:12)
    at Walker._wNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:272:17)
    at Walker._wNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:272:17)
    at Walker._wNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:272:17)
    at Walker._wNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:272:17)
    at Walker._wOnEmitDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:124:8)
    at nextWhenReady (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/node-type-emitter.js:69:29)
    at Object.emitPluralEvents [as emitNodeTypeGroups] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/node-type-emitter.js:77:5)
    at Walker._wPostFilesHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:136:17)
    at Walker._wReadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:152:10)
    at Walker._wReaddirHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:169:10)
    at Walker._wWalkSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:238:8)
    at Walker._wNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:263:12)
    at Walker._wNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:272:17)
    at Walker._wOnEmitDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:124:8)
    at nextWhenReady (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/walk/lib/node-type-emitter.js:69:29)
```

Comment: `events.js` is written by you, right? Please share its code esp block around line 110.

Comment: No we did not added it the project. still I could not find the file as well

Comment: Ok, that is not your file. Are you calling callback synchronously in your code? Check example at https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#ensureasyncfn to understand sync v/s async calling.

Comment: Also see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936486/node-js-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded