# Issues with using ulimit to increase stack size for Node

Tags: node.js, ulimit

I would like to increase the call stack limit for my node process so that I can create, parse and serialize a recursive object that's about `100,000` layers deep. If I had more time, I should represent this in a better format.

But for a quick fix, there is a [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940085/1284735) to do something like:

```
/bin/bash -c "ulimit -s $n; exec /usr/local/bin/node --stack-size=$n app.js"
```

Are there any repercussions that I need to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `node --stack-size=2048 app.js` or any other amount in kbytes. But keep in mind, that this is not a production way. Higher value you'll put - more unstable app could become.

> As noted by others, be aware that increasing this value may lead to a segmentation fault. Looking at the bigger picture, increasing stack size may not solve all your issues. When writing recursive functions in node, your best strategy is to write them in a tail-recursive manner, since node supports proper tail calls. This will eliminate stack size overflows.