# Scope of variables and modules in Node.Js modules leading to RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, node-modules

I experienced a strange problem with external modules being launched several times arriving to the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error after a few iterations.

I will demonstrate what leads to this error using a simple construct. The question is how this construct can be made more efficient so that a particular variable does not overload the memory.

Suppose I have a module called `validate`. Let's imagine that `elem` is not an external module but actually a variable, for simplicity sake:

```
// validate.js

var elem = 0;

exports.testRun = function() {
    elem++
    console.log(elem)
}
```

and if I launch it from another place in my app (from `run.js`):

```
// run.js
 
var validate = require('validate')

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    validate.testRun()
}
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Which makes sense.

However, now imagine I make `run.js` into a module and run it from another place in the app — in that case for some reason my variable gets incremented, which I don't understand:

```
// validate.js

var elem = 0;

exports.testRun = function() {
    elem++
    console.log(elem)
}
// end of validate.js


// run.js
 
var validate = require('validate')

exports.otherRun = function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    validate.testRun()
  }
}

// end of run.js


// new.js

var otherone = require('./run')

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    otherone.otherRun()
}

// end of new.js
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
...
25
```

Which also makes sense, because the variable is defined in the global scope and is actually required once and then reiterated.

However, now a question: what would be the most efficient way to declare this variable (without sending it between the modules) so that it would get reset every time the loop in the `new.js` is launched? The output would then be `1234512345` etc.

I'm asking this because I encountered some problems with external modules that need to be declared as variables and when dealing with loops I discovered that they would run into `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. So I'm trying to understand where in the module / export function I should declare them for maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the current `for` loop index into `testRun`, and if it is `0`, set `elem` equal to `0`. I also generally advise switching from `var` to `let`. See below:

```
// validate.js

let elem
exports.testRun = function(i) {
    if (i === 0) {
      elem = 0
    } else {
      elem++
    }
    console.log(elem)
}

// run.js
 
let validate = require('validate')

exports.otherRun = function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    validate.testRun(i)
  }
}
```

A `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error is likely to be a result of recursion, not a loop per se, although a `while` loop running infinitely can cause this as well. (For that reason I use `for` loops whenever possible.) An excellent, thorough discussion about this may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936486/node-js-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded). It is not possible to give further detail without additional code examples, as the earliest part of this answer addresses the specific case you provide.

Comment: sure, this would be one way to do that, but my question was more general about the use of modules in Node.Js

Comment: In that case, you may want to rephrase your original post, because the question you directly pose is the one answered above. Since you've clarified, I'll update my answer.