# NodeJS - setTimeout(fn,0) vs setImmediate(fn)

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the difference between those two, and when will I use one over the other?

Comment: Related [setImmediate Vs nextTick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick)

Comment: I learned today that setImmediate( ) is just outright missing from Chrome

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**setTimeout** is simply like calling the function after delay has finished. Whenever a function is called it is not executed immediately, but queued so that it is executed after all the executing and currently queued eventhandlers finish first. setTimeout(,0) essentially means execute after all current functions in the present queue get executed. No guarantees can be made about how long it could take.

**setImmediate** is similar in this regard except that it doesn't use queue of functions. It checks queue of I/O eventhandlers. If all I/O events in the current snapshot are processed, it executes the callback. It queues them immediately after the last I/O handler somewhat like process.nextTick. So it is faster.

Also (setTimeout,0) will be slow because it will check the timer at least once before executing. At times it can be twice as slow. Here is a benchmark.

```
var Suite = require('benchmark').Suite
var fs = require('fs')

var suite = new Suite

suite.add('deffered.resolve()', function(deferred) {
  deferred.resolve()
}, {defer: true})

suite.add('setImmediate()', function(deferred) {
  setImmediate(function() {
    deferred.resolve()
  })
}, {defer: true})

suite.add('setTimeout(,0)', function(deferred) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve()
  },0)
}, {defer: true})

suite
.on('cycle', function(event) {
  console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'));
})
.run({async: true})
```

Output

```
deffered.resolve() x 993 ops/sec Â±0.67% (22 runs sampled)
setImmediate() x 914 ops/sec Â±2.48% (57 runs sampled)
setTimeout(,0) x 445 ops/sec Â±2.79% (82 runs sampled)
```

First one gives idea of fastest possible calls. You can check yourself if setTimeout gets called  half as many times as other. Also remember setImmediate will adjust to your filesystem calls. So under load it will perform less. I don't think setTimeout can do better.

setTimeout is un-intrusive way of calling functions after some time. Its just like its in the browser. It may not be suited for server-side (think why I used benchmark.js not setTimeout).

Comment: It's important to note that setTimeout is subject to a forced delay of at least four milliseconds if nested five times.  [see html spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timers)

Comment: This source (from the other answer) seems to refute some of the statements here: http://voidcanvas.com/setimmediate-vs-nexttick-vs-settimeout/

Comment: suppose setTimeout and setImmediate are used in main module (not i/o) , so when main module code is completed, event loop will start its phase,1st phase is timer so why would timer (0 ms) not get executed before setimmediate (which is executed in 5th phase) ? please clear confusion

Answer (score 27):

A great article about how event loop works and clears some misconceptions. 
http://voidcanvas.com/setimmediate-vs-nexttick-vs-settimeout/

Citing the article:

`setImmediate` callbacks are called after I/O Queue callbacks are finished or timed out. setImmediate callbacks are placed in Check Queue, which are processed after I/O Queue.

`setTimeout(fn, 0)` callbacks are placed in Timer Queue and will be called after I/O callbacks as well as Check Queue callbacks. As event loop, process the timer queue first in each iteration, so which one will be executed first depends on which phase event loop is.

Comment: setTimeout queue is processed before I/O callbacks. ref: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: yes setTimeout is in 1st phase while setImmediate is in 5th phase, not sure what author of this answer meant by `as well as Check Queue callbacks`

Answer (score 5):

**setImmediate()** is  to schedule the immediate execution of callback after I/O events callbacks and before setTimeout and setInterval .

**setTimeout()** is to schedule execution of a one-time callback after delay milliseconds.

**This is what the documents say.**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout')
}, 0)

setImmediate(function() {
  console.log('setImmediate')
})
```

If you run the above code, the result will be like this... even though the current doc states that "To schedule the "immediate" execution of callback after I/O events callbacks and before setTimeout and setInterval." ..

Result..

> setTimeout
>
> setImmediate

If you wrap your example in another timer, it always prints setImmediate followed by setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('setTimeout')
  }, 0);
  setImmediate(function() {
    console.log('setImmediate')
  });
}, 10);
```

Comment: So when will you prefer one over the other?

Comment: You did not explain why what you showed happens. This answer wasn't useful to me.

Comment: @Savannah In your first result, please explain why setTimeout executed first before setImmediate

Comment: @AgusSyahputra Check this out: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/25788

Comment: SetImmediate wont execute before  setTimeout and setInterval  all times

Comment: For both examples the other of output is not certain. it can be anything depending on the current state of Event Loop

Comment: @Midhun can u explain ur reasoning behind saying setImmediate won't execute setTimeout/Interval, as per node docs https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/  Timeout or Intervals will execute first because the timer phase comes before the check phase, also there it's mentioned -> Technically, the poll phase controls when timers are executed.

Comment: In the first example, setTimeout will be printed before setImmediate in typical browser environment. setImmediate will be printed before setTimeout in Nodejs environment. This is because setImmediate is a Node.js-specific function that is used to execute a callback function after the current event loop cycle.

Answer (score 2):

always use `setImmediate`, unless you are really sure that you need `setTimeout(,0)` (but I can't even imagine, what for). `setImmediate` callback will almost always be executed before `setTimeout(,0)`, except  when called in first tick and in `setImmediate` callback.

Comment: I would say the main reason to use setTimeout instead of setImmediate is your code needs to be executed by browsers which don't have setImmediate implemented. Even then, you can just create a shim.

Comment: This is unsound advice.  If everything asks to go first, the emergent performance characteristics of asynchronous execution are going to being junk compared to queue-ing at the end.  `setTimeout` should be the go-to, with `setImmediate` used only when shown to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To understand them deeply please once go through the event loop phases.

**SetImmediate:**
 It gets executed in the "check" phase. The **check** phase is called after the I/O phase.

**SetTimeOut:** 
 It gets executed in the "timer" phase. The **timer** phase is the first phase but is called after the **I/O** phase as well as the **Check** phase.

To get the output in a deterministic manner, it will depend on which phase the event-loop is; accordingly, we can use the function out of two.

Comment: `The timer phase is the first phase but is called after the I/O phase as well as the Check phase.` what do you mean by this ? what is use if being 1st phase then

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of *Navya S* is not correct, here is my test code:

```
let set = new Set();

function orderTest() {
  let seq = [];
  let add = () => set.add(seq.join());
  setTimeout(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      seq.push('setTimeout');
      if (seq.length === 2) add();
    }, 0);

    setImmediate(function () {
      seq.push('setImmediate');
      if (seq.length === 2) add();
    });
  }, 10);
}

// loop 100 times
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  orderTest();
}

setTimeout(() => {
  // will print one or two items, it's random
  for (item of set) {
    console.log(item);
  }
}, 100);
```

The explanations is [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(fn,0) can be used for preventing the browser from freezing in massive update. for example in websocket.onmessage, you may have html changes, and if messages keep coming, the browser may freeze when using setImmidiate

Answer (score -1):

When the Javascript engine starts execution, It checks code line by line.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout')
}, 0)

setImmediate(function() {
  console.log('setImmediate')
})
```

When it comes to

`settimeout`, it moves from call-stack to call queue and starts a timer for execution.

`setimmediate`, it moves from call-stack to macro-queue(which is start execution immediately after the first loop is complete)

So, if `settimeout` value is 0, it will complete its timer before call-stack loop complete.

that's why, `settimeout` will print before `setimmediate`.

Now, suppose

```
setTimeout(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('setTimeout')
  }, 0);
  setImmediate(function() {
    console.log('setImmediate')
  });
}, 10);
```

This means, first main timeout move to call-queue. meanwhile, call-stack complete its execution.

So, after 10ms, function comes to call stack, it will direct execute `setimmediate`. Because call-stack is already free to execute task.

Comment: According to the docs `setImmediate` is a macro task not micro https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-setimmediate

Answer (score -5):

use setImmediate() for not blocking the event loop.  The callback will run on the next event loop, as soon as the current one is done.

use setTimeout() for controlled delays.  The function will run after the specified delay.  The minimum delay is 1 millisecond.