# How setImmediate is different from setTimeout(fn, 0)

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

Which all phases exactly `setImmediate` and `setTimeout` goes through.

It's not well-explained what all phases exactly setImmediate and setTimeout goes through, please see the nodeJS [guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) once there the Phases Overview section says that I/O callback phase is responsible for setImmediate and again in poll and check section says check phase is responsible for setImmediate. 
so I am a bit confused with it. IO/callback or check or both.

Can somebody please explain the life cycle of the `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` inside the event loop and how they execute.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117267/nodejs-settimeoutfn-0-vs-setimmediatefn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS - setTimeout(fn,0) vs setImmediate(fn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117267/nodejs-settimeoutfn-0-vs-setimmediatefn)

Comment: It's not well-explained what all phases exactly setImmediate and setTimeout goes through, please see the nodeJS [doc](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-l) once there the **Phases Overview** section says that **I/O callback** phase is responsible for setImmediate and again in **poll** and **check** section says **check** phase is responsible for setImmediate. so I am a bit confused with it. **IO/callback** or **check** or both

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout callbacks are executed in the timers phase whereas setImmediate callbacks are executed in the check phase.

As the timers phase comes before the check phase, setTimeout(fn,0) will be executed before setImmediate call back.

The docs also mention it, below I am quoting the poll phase in phase overview section where they have mentioned exceptions.

poll: retrieve new I/O events; execute I/O related callbacks (almost all with the **exception** of close callbacks, the ones **scheduled by timers, and setImmediate())**; node will block here when appropriate.