# setTimeout later than Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Run **below sample**, you will see **setTimeout** callbacks always are executed later than **Promise** callback. Are there **any mechanisms** causes this result? or this is not ture?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(1)
}, 0)

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  resolve(2)
}).then(console.log)

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(3)
}, 0)

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  resolve(4)
}).then(console.log)

console.log('rush...')
```

Comment: Have a look at [this great response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117267/nodejs-settimeoutfn-0-vs-setimmediatefn) on stackoverflow

Comment: Related: [Promise vs setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752620/promise-vs-settimeout), [What is the order of execution in javascript promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870467/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-javascript-promises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native promises are scheduled as a microtask. When the current execution stack finishes, microtasks are run first, and regular tasks will happen after.

For more information on the event loop, including information on microtasks, i recommend this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0 . The section on microtasks begins at 24 minutes in.

Comment: this video is awesome. it is worth watching it frame by frame.

Comment: Just found [HTML SPEC: event loop processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model) describes the details as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is normal because **Javascript is single-threaded** and considering how did you wrote the code your Promises are executed in a synchronous way (while the script is been loaded) while the setTimeout are asynchronous (after the script have been loaded).