# Inconsistent Execution Order of setImmediate and setTimeout(0) in Node.js

Tags: node.js, settimeout, event-loop

I've noticed a seemingly inconsistent behavior regarding the execution order of setImmediate and setTimeout with a delay of 0 milliseconds in Node.js

```
setImmediate(() => {
  console.log('setImmediate callback');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('setTimeout callback');
}, 0);

console.log('This code runs first.');
```

```
i got this answer-

This code runs first.
setTimeout callback
setImmediate callback
```

but some times its changing,why?
like,

```
This code runs first.
setImmediate callback
setTimeout callback
```

Comment: I think you should check this question to find all answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117267/nodejs-settimeoutfn-0-vs-setimmediatefn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is timing of \`setImmediate()\` and \`setTimeout()\` bound by the performance of the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance-of)

Comment: And note that this only applies when ran as CJS.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such inconsistency. The code provided will always result in the first example. To understand why I say this so confidently (other than that I ran the provided code 10 thousand times to prove it to myself), you need to have an understanding on how NodeJS handles the event loop. Please refer to this diagram:

[image: NodeJS Event Loop Diagram]
(Source: https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick)

`setTimeout` is *scheduled* during the timers phase, though actual execution happens at the beginning of the poll phase.

`setImmediate` executes in the check phase when the poll phase becomes idle. `setImmediate` is supposed to be delayed until after the event queue is empty.

`setImmediate` ALWAYS happens second because they're executed in a different step.