# Promise.resolve().then vs setImmediate vs nextTick

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

NodeJS 0.11 as well as io.js and the Node 0.12 branch all ship with native promises.

Native promises [have a `.then` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which always executes on a future event loop cycle.

So far I've been using `setImmediate` to queue things to the next iteration of the event loop ever since I [switched from nextTick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick):

```
setImmediate(deferThisToNextTick); // My NodeJS 0.10 code
process.nextTick(deferThisToNextTick); // My NodeJS 0.8 code
```

Since we now have a new way to do this:

```
Promise.resolve().then(deferThisToNextTick);
```

Which should I use? Also - **does `Promise.resolve.then` act like `setImmediate` or like `nextTick` with regards to code running before or after the event loop?**

Comment: Sharing some research: In Chromium - a promise enqueues a microtask, here's run microtask https://github.com/yoavweiss/Blink/blob/80ec93f1d58a0a0ce99a07ed07c203a106b2a88c/Source/core/dom/Microtask.cpp called here when a script arrives or checked and no script is running: https://github.com/yoavweiss/Blink/blob/5be896b969d644c18facc30833210b07f43ae086/Source/core/html/parser/HTMLScriptRunner.cpp

Comment: Promise resolution https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/857975d5e7e0d7bf38577db0478d9e5ede79922e/deps/v8/src/promise.js#L154 - calls https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/857975d5e7e0d7bf38577db0478d9e5ede79922e/deps/v8/src/execution.cc#L321 - gets to https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/857975d5e7e0d7bf38577db0478d9e5ede79922e/deps/v8/src/execution.cc#L310

Comment: Very related: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7714

Comment: More sauce: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12/src/node.js#L305

Comment: Verified  microtasks run on the nextTick queue:  https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12/src/node.js#L326-L329 , going to wait a few hours to see if a v8 or node team member feels like clarifying and if not I'll write my answer.

Comment: You can share this question in that github discussion, so that they might come here and answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using `Promise.resolve().then` has no advantages over `nextTick`. It runs on the same queue, but have slightly higher priority, that is, promise handler can prevent next tick callback from ever running, the opposite is not possible. This behaviour is an implementation detail and should not be relied on.

`Promise.resolve().then` is obviously slower (a lot, I think), because it creates two promises which will be thrown away.

You can find extensive implementation info here: https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/8325

The most important part: `Promise.resolve().then` is like `nextTick` and not like `setImmediate`. Using it n place of `setImmediate` can change your code behaviour drastically.

Comment: Upvoted. I would love to see an example for the last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks this sounds correct and what I've observed at the code too. It would be nice if you could elaborate on when to use either and why it works this way. @thefourtheye any example of where `nextTick` wouldn't work instead of `setImmediate` - neither would `Promise.resolve().then`

Comment: What I mean is you should not use `Promise.resolve().then` at all. This trick achieves nothing. Regarding nextTick vs setImmediate there is a lot of info

Comment: "It runs on the same queue, but have slightly higher priority..."

Actually, not really. Each one has its own mechanism to handle the queue of callbacks.

Comment: Well, microtask queue is flushed inside `nextTick` queue, that's what I meant. The intention was to make this behave as one queue as much as possible

Comment: @vkurchatkin why does this create two promises?  "Promise.resolve().then is obviously slower (a lot, I think), because it creates two promises which will be thrown away" ?

Comment: Promise.resolve() creates the first one, .then() creates the second one

Answer (score 10):

<sub>I'm not going to answer the bolded part about technicalities, but only the question</sub>

> Which should I use?

I don't think there is any reason to use `Promise.resolve().then()` unless you are interested in the promise for the result of your asynchronously executed function. Of course, if you *are*, then this would be far superior than dealing with callback hell or making a `new Promise` from `setTimeout` or `nextTick`.

There's also a second technical difference, more import than the timing: promises do swallow exceptions. Which you probably don't want. So, like @vkurchatkin mentioned, don't create promises only to throw them away. Not only because it's slower, but because it makes your code less readable and your app more error-prone.

Answer (score -5):

Promise.resolve would be resolved straight away (syncroniously), while setImmediate explicitly straight after the execution of current event.

Comment: Try this in your browser console to see you're wrong: `Promise.resolve([]).then(function(){ console.log('1'); }); console.log('2');`

Comment: I think you are confusing it with new `Promise((res, rej) => res());`. The above example `new Promise((res) => { console.log(1); res(); }); console.log(2);`. In that case `1` will get printed before `2`.