# Node.js event loop - Why is order of execution of callbacks in promise queue vs nextTick queue reversed in CJS vs ES modules?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I am unable to find any documentation on why the order of execution is `nextTick` queue followed by `promise` queue for CJS modules whereas `promise` queue followed by `nextTick` queue for ES modules. Any insight appreciated!

```
// index.js (CJS)
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("this is Promise.resolve 1"));
process.nextTick(() => console.log("this is process.nextTick 1"));
```

Logs "this is process.nextTick 1" and then "this is Promise.resolve 1"

```
// index.mjs (ESM)
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("this is Promise.resolve 1"));
process.nextTick(() => console.log("this is process.nextTick 1"));
```

Logs "this is Promise.resolve 1" and then "this is process.nextTick 1"

Comment: Probably because in ESM you're actually in an async function (global async), and thus the microtask end-point would get visited before the nextTick one (since you're basically already in the microtask-checkpoint). Though that might require to be checked in the sources, and I never took the time to do so. (That question has already been asked, but I don't think it ever got an answer).

Comment: Found it, that was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518968

Comment: Seems like there is no concrete explanation anywhere though righ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [process.nextTick vs queueMicrotask in commonJs and ESM. What is the execution order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518968/process-nexttick-vs-queuemicrotask-in-commonjs-and-esm-what-is-the-execution-or)