# Is execution of main thread javascript code a macro-task?

Tags: javascript, event-loop, task-queue

I was reading [this](https://towardsdev.com/event-loop-in-javascript-672c07618dc9) blog about event loop and micro/macrotask queues in javascript but I have doubts about the statements from the blog:

> In JavaScript, no code is allowed to execute until an event has occurred. It is worth mentioning that the **execution of a JavaScript code execution is itself a macro-task**.

> Macro-tasks include parsing HTML, generating DOM, **executing main thread JavaScript code**, and other events such as page loading, input, network events, timer events, etc. Examples: setTimeout, setInterval, setImmediate,requestAnimationFrame, I/O, UI Rendering.

What I know is  that execution of the javascript code can't be macro-task unless it is user interaction like a click, setTimeout etc.

I don't get this beacause all I know is that macrotasks and microtask are generally asynchronous operations and execution of main thread javascript code is synchronous codes like `console.log("hello")` . Correct me please if I am mistaken.

By the way, I'm  referring to the execution of main thread JavaScript code in the context of script tag in html within a browser environment. Also let's assume that script is linked as a external file(not directly embedded within HTML)

Comment: Completely depends on which type of scripts, in which environment at what time. Please clarify.

Comment: I did, let me know  If you need further details,

Comment: Yes, what is "the execution of main thread JavaScript" for you? Do you mean the content of a `<script>` tag? What kind of script tag? How has it been created? All that will determine if you're in a task or in a microtask.

Comment: @AndrewParks given your answer I'll say you don't know much about the subject matter. You don't seem to understand what is a task. And from `document.write()` for instance you can be in any state of the event loop.

Comment: Too bad tasks and microtasks are defined by HTML and not JS then.

Comment: @Kaiido I added details to my post as I understand like: script tag in html within a browser environment and  script is linked as a external file

Comment: @AndrewParks Well, events are fired synchronously, not necessarily in a task, the fetch algorithm will queue a task that does much more than just executing a callback, and actually the JS callback will get pushed to a microtask because `fetch()` returns a Promise, And I don't get how you derive that it makes sense the main scripts are executed in a task, they could achieve the same behavior from a microtask.

Comment: @AndrewParks This article says that task do run js, not that tasks are js. And `fetch` does [queue a task to queue a microtask.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566665/3702797)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, that makes sense. I think you are saying that: The Javascript engine has no concept of the task queue, and only has a microtask queue (known as the microtask queue in the HTML spec, and as the "job" queue in the ECMAScript spec). Only when the microtask queue is empty will the browser then continue with executing "tasks". "Tasks" include tasks that run JS, and tasks that perform other non-JS functions such as parsing HTML. My misconception, therefore, was to consider the task queue to be only JS-related, when, in fact, JS-related tasks are only one type of task?

Comment: @Kaiido in other words, there is no Javascript-only "macrotask" queue, and the term "macrotask queue" is really a simplification used in articles in order to only refer to JS-related tasks in the browser's task queue? This is why my understanding seemed functionally correct from a JS-only perspective, yet technically incorrect.

Comment: Yes and no. There are various task-queues, but they aren't JS concepts. They are more like infra concepts used to specify how browsers should work. Not all browsers actually use tasks as they are defined, for instance Safari doesn't yet. Chrome and Firefox do really have task concepts though. But what matters is that when the specs say to queue a task, that task is gonna do more than just JS. A browser is not just a JS engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of script you're talking about, and which environment.

For HTML, most of the time you'll be in a task (there is no such thing as a **macro**task, only [tasks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task) and [microtasks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#microtask)).

For instance inline scripts met by the parser when the browser [navigates](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#navigate) will be executed from the *global task* the *navigate*  algorithm queued. External scripts will be executed from the *fetch task* that got queued when fetching the script's content. `defer` scripts [will be executed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end) after the browser [spinned the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop), which will itself queue a task to then run the script.

But, you could force being in a microtask too. For instance doing

```js
queueMicrotask(() => document.write("<script>alert('from a microtask')<\/script>"));
```

Here when the parser meets the inline script, it's still in the microtask that launched it, so the script is executed from that microtask.

---

In node, CommonJS scripts are executed from ... a magic point which is called *the main module*. It's not really a task, but it's not a microtask. ESM scripts on the other hand [are executed from a microtask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378403/3702797)(, itself [queued from an IO task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77784120/3702797)).

Comment: When you say "task" you mean "micro-task", right?

Comment: Where? Tasks are tasks and microtasks are microtasks, did I mess somewhere in my answer?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant macro-task actually, task is macro-task, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah if you will, though macro-task isn't the correct term, it's just task.

Comment: @Kaiido could you point where the _global task_ appears in the navigates for inline scripts? Also I would like to know where the _fetch task_ enqueues for the external scripts. I ask it because there are lot of places such as _global tasks_ and _fetch tasks_

Comment: @MaximPro, Navigate queues a task in step 7. For classic scripts the fetch is done in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-classic-script step 5 and the task would be queued in https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-fetch-params-process-response-consume-body%E2%91%A1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Kaiido these algorithms in whatwg are a real rabbit hole. And one thing, you mentioned the step 7 in navigates. Have you read that step? I am not sure that I understand it, because that step separated on *if-otherwise* sections. Could you explain please, if you understand of  course.

Comment: @MaximPro the note below makes it quite clear what step 7 actually does: if we're navigating in the same doc (hashchange), continue sync, otherwise continue in a task. During the parsing of the doc we're in the latter case. But unless you're writing a browser, you shouldn't need to know all these details.

Comment: Oh and for the fetch case it's actually in https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-fully-read, I mistakenly linked to the previous step.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for explanation, I think I'll ask new question here, about scripts and their priority of executing with specs integration. This is important thing for the devs in general.