# How do I write an app using a recursive function that can be started / stopped

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, promise

I have an app that needs to run a function continuously. That function returns a promise. I want the app to wait until the promise is resolved before it starts the function again.

Additionally, my app needs a `start` and `stop` function that causes it to either start running the function, or stop it respectively.

I have a simplified example here:

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.running = false
    this.cycles = 0
  }

  start() {
    this.running = true
    this._run()
  }

  stop() {
    this.running = false
  }

  _run() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      this.cycles++
    }).then(() => {
      if (this.running) {
        this._run()
      }
    })
  }
}

module.exports = App
```

My problem is that when I use this, `setTimeout` seems to give up on me. For example, if I run this:

const App = require("./app")

```
const a = new App()

a.start()

console.log("a.start is not blocking...")

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("This will never get logged")
  a.stop()
  console.log(a.cycles)
}, 500)
```

The output will be:

```
a.start is not blocking...
```

And then the code in the `setTimeout` callback never gets called.

I can try starting running `node` on my command line and typing directly into the REPL, but after I call `a.start()` the terminal freezes up and I can no longer type anything.

This kind of thing seems like it should be a pretty common pattern. For example, Express lets you start/stop a server without these issues. What do I need to do to get that behavior?

Comment: This type of applications are called 'Services'. I know in the .Net world, you can create a project with type of 'Windows Service' and then register it as a service on any computer, stop/start it using the Control panel/Administrative tools/Services. I think you should look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_run()` method is infinite.  It never stops calling itself unless other code can run and change the value of `this.running` but just using a `.then()` is not enough to reliably allow your other `setTimeout()` code to run because `.then()` runs at a higher priority than timer events in the event queue.

While `.then()` is guaranteed to be asynchronous, it will be run at a higher priority than `setTimeout()` meaning your recursive call just runs indefinitely and your other `setTimeout()` never gets to run and thus `this.running` never gets changed.

If instead, you call `_run()` recursively with a short `setTimeout()` itself, then your other `setTimeout()` will get a chance to run.  And, since there's really no need to use promises there at all, you can just remove them:

Change it to this:

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.running = false
    this.cycles = 0
  }

  start() {
    this.running = true
    this._run()
  }

  stop() {
    this.running = false
  }

  _run() {
      this.cycles++
      if (this.running) {
         // call recursively after a short timeout to allow other code
         // a chance to run
         setTimeout(this._run.bind(this), 0);
      }
  }
}

module.exports = App
```

See this other answer for some discussion of the relative priorities between `.then()`, `setImmediate()` and `nextTick()`:

[Promise.resolve().then vs setImmediate vs nextTick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647742/promise-resolve-then-vs-setimmediate-vs-nexttick)

And more info on the subject in this:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/pull/8325

---

The generalized priority hierarchy seems to be:

```
.then()
nextTick()
other events already in the queue
setImmediate()
setTimeout()
```

So, you can see from this that `.then()` jumps in front of other events already in the queue, thus your `setTimeout()` nevers gets to run as long as their is a `.then()` waiting to go.

So, if you want to allow other timer events already in the queue to run before your next call to `this._run()`, you have to use either `setImmediate()` or `setTimeout()`.  Probably either will work in this case, but since the other events are `setTimeout()`, I figured using `setTimeout()` here would guarantee safety since you know a new `setTimeout()` callback can't jump in front of one that is already a pending event.

Answer (score 1):

### Blocking Recursive `Promise`s

This is actually a good example for a "blocking" `Promise` in connection with recursion.

Your first `console.log` invocation is executed as expected. It is a synchronous operation and due to the [run-to-completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion) scheduling in Javascript, it is guaranteed to run in the current iteration of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Event_loop).

Your second `console.log` is asynchronous and due to the implementation of `setTimeout` it is attached to the queue of the **next iteration** of the event loop. However, this next iteration is never reached, because `Promise.resolve().then(...)` attaches the `then` callback to the end of the queue of the **current iteration**. Since this is done recursively, the current iteration is never completed.

Hence your second `log`, which is queued at the next turn of the event loop, never logs.

With node.js you can reproduce this behavior by implementing a recursive function with `setImmediate`:

```
// watch out: this functions is blocking!

function rec(x) {
  return x === Infinity
   ? x
   : (console.log(x), setImmediate(rec, x + 1));
}
```

Bergi's implementation simply bypasses the normal asynchronous `Promise` behavior by applying `setTimeout` to the resolve callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_run` method is running too fast. It's using promises and is asynchronous, so you don't get a stack overflow or something, but the promise task queue is running on a higher priority than the timeout task queue. That's why your `setTimeout` callback will never be fired.

If you use an actual long-running task instead of `Promise.resolve()`, it will work.

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.running = false
    this.cycles = 0
  }

  start() {
    if (this.running) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Already running"))
    } else {
      this.running = true
      return this._run()
    }
  }

  stop() {
    this.running = false
  }

  _run() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.cycles++
      setTimeout(resolve, 5) // or something
    }).then(() => {
      if (this.running)
        return this._run()
      else
        return this.cycles
    })
  }
}
```