# Wrapping my head around Promise and then

Tags: node.js, promise

Ive read plenty of articles on Promises and I feel i'm still missing something.  Here is an example of what i'm trying to wrap my head around.

```
File: ad.js

// Using node.js activedirectory

class AD
{
    constuctor(options){
        this.ad = new ActiveDirectory(options);
    }

    isUserValid(user, password){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{            
            ad.authenticate(user, password, (err, auth) ->{
                if(err){
                    reject({ code: 500, message: 'Unknow error'});
                }

                if(auth){
                    resolve({code: 200, message: 'ok'});
                }           
            });
        )
    }
}

module.exports = {
    AD: AD
}


File: session.js

createSession(user, password){
    var self = this;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        const ad = new AD("Required parameters"); 

        Code: 1
        const result = self._isADValid(ad, user, password);

        Code: 2
        self._isADValidPromise(ad, user, password)
        .then(resp_ad =>{
        })
        .catch(err =>{
        }); 
    );
}

_isADValidPromise(ad, user, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ad.isUserValid(user, password)
            .then(resp_ad => {
                resolv(resp_ad);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
}
_isADValid(ad, user, password) {
    return ad.isUserValid(user, password)
        .then(resp_ad => {
            return resp_ad;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
}
```

What i'm trying to understand is the following:

Shouldnt "Code 1" return a value from _isADValid.  Instead its returning "Promise{ pending }".  I though that you only need to use then/catch from a Promise?
So the function _isADValid() is calling the AD function isUserValid which is returning from a Promise and _isADValid() is wrapped in a then/catch which just returns the result.

Code 2 using "_isADValidPromise" works without any issues.  And I get that its wrapped in a Promise so its doing what I expected.

If anyone can help clarify why Code 1 is not working

Comment: You have typo: ```resolve```, not ```resolv```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it.  The same problem.  I just typed in incorrectly on stackoverflow

Comment: Also, it looks like `ad.authenticate(...)` should be `this.ad.authentication(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that Promises don't resolve until (at least) the next tick (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647742/promise-resolve-then-vs-setimmediate-vs-nexttick)). You're expecting the Promise to return synchronously, but Promises are by definition asynchronous.

Your example demonstrates this: If you think about it, your call to `authenticate` is very likely asynchronous - reaching out to some server to authenticate the user. Promises were invented to wrap asynchronous operations such as this one in a way that provides a nice control flow and avoids callback hell. So in short, any time you use a Promise, it will return asynchronously.

In that light, `self._isADValid(ad, user, password);` returns a Promise, so naturally, `result` is a Promise. The only way to get the result out of it is to add a `.then()` and wait for it to resolve, which will always be at least one tick into the future.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Taking what you wrote and making more examples to clarify help me clarify it.  Thank you for the response