# Strange async code behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have an unsolved JS behavior that I cannot understand.
I'm running this code on `node v8.4.0`.
I'm running this code twice.

First time with `f1()`
second time with `f2()`

`f2()` the result is as expected. 'start' is printed first and then 'end'.

`f1()` the result is not as expected. 'end' is printed first and then 'start'.

Can someone please explain to me the result of the code below?

```
const fs = require('fs')

function f1() { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve() }) }

function f2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('/Users/adi/Downloads/profile.jpg', resolve)
    })
}

async function main() {

    setImmediate(() => { console.log('start') })
    await f1()
    console.log('end')
} 

main()

//f1 output:
end
start

//f2 output:
start
end
```

As far as I know, the result should be 'start' and then 'end'.
What am I missing?

Comment: i wonder if the `Promise` constructor is simplifying the result.

Comment: So, what you're really asking is about a race between `setImmediate()` and the `.then()` handler of an immediately resolved promise?  The answer is because of the internals of how different async things like `setImmediate()` and promises are coded to work (micro tasks).  If you care about the order between the two, then write your code for a specific order rather than rely on that level of internal design detail.

Comment: `setImmediate` is _very_ unfortunately named, it does _anything_ but run the code immediately - it actually runs it _after_ all microtasks (promises and await) and _after_ `nextTick` (which does _not_ run on the next tick but rather is a microtask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue with the resolved Promises will be check before the queue with `setImmediate(() => { console.log('start') })`

Because the `f1` resolves immediately, both the callback of the `setImmediate`  and the resolved  Promise are added to the event queue at the same time, but at different stages. Resolved Promises have a higher priority then callbacks added with `setImmediate`

If you use `process.nextTick`  then the callback will be added with an higher  priority then `setImmediate` and `start`  will be logged before `end`

```
function f1() { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve() }) }

async function main() {
    process.nextTick(() => { console.log('start') })
    setImmediate(() => { console.log('start') })
    await f1()
    console.log('end')
} 

main()
```

For `f2` the reading of the file will involve a longer lasting async task so the `setImmediat`  will be still called before.

Comment: More info https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa and https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 1):

So, in your `f1()` example, you have a race between `setImmediate()` and the `.then()` handler of an immediately resolved promise since both will be in the event queue at the time the next event is ready to be processed.

When both are ready to run, one runs before the other because of the internals of how different async things like `setImmediate()` and promises are coded to work in the node.js implementation of its event loop. Internal to the event loop in node.js, there is a sequence or priority for some different types of asynchronous operations and some go before others if all are waiting to go.  It is possible, though difficult, to fully understand which goes before the others, but it is very complicated and it is mostly an implementation detail, not something fully documented by specification.

In this specific case, native promises in node.js use a microTasks queue (there are apparently a couple separate microTasks queues) and they are run before things like `setImmediate()`, timers and I/O events.

But, in general, it is best to not rely on fully understanding all that and, if you want one thing to happen before the other, don't allow it to be a race between the two inside of node.js.  Just code it with your own code to force the sequence you want.  This also makes your code more obvious and declarative what order you expect things to be processed in.

If I read your current code, I would think that you purposely set up a race between `f1()` and `setImmediate()` and did not care which one ran first because the code is not declarative and does not define a desired order.

For more info on the details of the internals of different types of async operations in the event loop, you can read these references:

[Promise.resolve().then vs setImmediate vs nextTick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647742/promise-resolve-then-vs-setimmediate-vs-nexttick)

[Promises, Next-Ticks and Immediates— NodeJS Event Loop Part 3](https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa)

[Promises wiggle their way between `nextTick` and `setImmediate`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2736)

Here's a quote from this last reference article:

> Native promise handlers are executed on a microtask queue which is roughly the same as nextTick, so they run before everything else. Pure javascript [promise] implementations should use nextTick for scheduling.

---

For your `f2()` example, it's probably just that `fs.readFile()` takes some finite amount of time so `f2()` does not resolve immediately and thus isn't ready to run at the same time that `setImmediate()` is so the `setImmediate()` runs before `f2()` resolves.

Comment: We actually absolutely guarantee that timers run after promises. There is actually one buggy edge case where it won't happen now - but in general it's absolutely the intention of the Node.js project as well as browser behaviour. You still shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's true that promises "use the microtask queue", there are actually two microtask queues: Node's and V8's. Promises use the V8 microtask queue (RunMicrotasks) whereas `nextTick` queued tasks are served internally.

Answer (score 0):

It's works like this, because `Promise` is a microtask. Microtasks are executed at the end of call stack, before macrotasks. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915634/difference-between-microtask-and-macrotask-within-an-event-loop-context)