# Node + Express: Does Express clone the req and res objects for each request handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If Javascript copies objects by reference, then does Express clone the `req` and `res` objects before passing them down to each request handler? If not, then how does Express handle possible conflicts between routes running simultaneously and using the same reference to `req` and `res`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Express doesn't clone `req` and `res`. You can see that in this example app:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var testReq, testRes;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('middleware');
  testReq = req;
  testRes = res;
  next();
});

app.get("*", function(req,res) {
  console.log('route')
  console.log('req the same? ' + (req === testReq)); // logs true
  console.log('res the same? ' + (res === testRes)); // logs true

  res.send(200);
});


http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

Test with `curl`:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
```

This is a useful feature - it means that middleware functions can use `req` and `res` to pass data to downstream functions. For example an authorisation middleware might add a `req.user` property.

Concurrency isn't a concern here because Node.js is single threaded - it is not possible for two routes to run at any given time.

It also doesn't run a single request through multiple routes - you can add another `get("*")` route and you'll see that it won't get called.

Comment: So, does that mean that routes in node/express are blocking? Will an expensive computation in route A block the execution of routes B, C and D, should a new request come to them?

Comment: No, all I/O in Node is non-blocking by default. That's why so many functions take callbacks - they are invoked asynchronously when the operation has finished.

Comment: I missed the part about expensive computation - yes, CPU-bound code can block. It's good practice to split slow computations across call stacks. You can do that with [`setImmediate` or `process.nextTick`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick) or a helper library like `async`.

Comment: Or better yet, reverse proxy into multiple instances of the same server.

Comment: Reverse proxying is great for load balancing but you should still avoid blocking the event loop in a single Node process.

Answer (score 2):

As JavaScript is single threaded, there is no simultaneous route handling and no multithreading pitfalls exist. `req` & `res` are not cloned, they are extended.

Answer (score 0):

When we say *parallel requests*, it means the client is creating a connection stream and gives it in the form of `request` or whatever you name it as.

A sequence of middleware will get it sequentially one after the other, based on the call to `next`, while getting appended with necessary things from middleware.

But the `router.all/*('path', [middleware])` triggers for each request made by the clients.