# Node.js process.nextTick still blocking server from getting requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, event-loop

I got this piece of code :

```js
import http from 'http';

function compute() {
  let [sum, i] = [1, 1];
  while (i<1000000000) {
    5*2 
    i++;
  }
  console.log("good");
  process.nextTick(compute);
}

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World');
}).listen(5000, '127.0.0.1');

http.request({hostname: '127.0.0.1', port: 5000}, (response) => {
  console.log("here !");
}).end();

compute();
```

the output for that is always : "good, "good" ...
and the HTTP request didn't get called.
I thought that process.nextTick should solve that problem, but server is still blocked. Why ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `process.nextTick` rather use set `setImmediate`. Callbacks passed to `nextTick` are processed before IO callbacks whereas callbacks passed to `setImmediate` are processed after any that are already pending.

Replace `process.nextTick(compute);` with `setImmediate(compute);`.

Moving the CPU work to a child process or worker is also possible. But I won't describe that as my main point was to explain how:

```
function compute() {
  ...
  console.log("good");
  process.nextTick(compute);
}
```

would block the HTTP server from handling requests ignoring the `while` loop which has its own problem.

See [setImmediate vs. nextTick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick) for more.