# Testing with React's Jest and Enzyme when simulated clicks call a function that calls a promise

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, promise, jestjs, enzyme

- React  v15.1.0
- Jest   v12.1.1
- Enzyme v2.3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to test a component that calls a promise in a function invoked by a click. I was expecting Jest's `runAllTicks()` function to help me out here, but it doesn't seem to be executing the promise.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

function doSomethingWithAPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 50);
  });
}

export default class AsyncTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      promiseText: '',
      timeoutText: ''
    };

    this.setTextWithPromise = this.setTextWithPromise.bind(this);
    this.setTextWithTimeout = this.setTextWithTimeout.bind(this);
  }

  setTextWithPromise() {
    return doSomethingWithAPromise()
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ promiseText: 'there is text!' });
      });
  }

  setTextWithTimeout() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ timeoutText: 'there is text!' });
    }, 50);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="promiseText">{this.state.promiseText}</div>
        <button id="promiseBtn" onClick={this.setTextWithPromise}>Promise</button>
        <div id="timeoutText">{this.state.timeoutText}</div>
        <button id="timeoutBtn" onClick={this.setTextWithTimeout}>Timeout</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the tests:

```
import AsyncTest from '../async';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

jest.unmock('../async');

describe('async-test.js', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<AsyncTest />);
  });

  // FAIL
  it('displays the promise text after click of the button', () => {
    wrapper.find('#promiseBtn').simulate('click');

    jest.runAllTicks();
    jest.runAllTimers();

    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find('#promiseText').text()).toEqual('there is text!');
  });

  // PASS
  it('displays the timeout text after click of the button', () => {
    wrapper.find('#timeoutBtn').simulate('click');

    jest.runAllTimers();

    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find('#timeoutText').text()).toEqual('there is text!');
  });
});
```

Comment: you can instead pass doSomethingWithAPromise function as a prop to AsyncTest component so that you can mock it inside your test:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308214/react-enzyme-test-componentdidmount-async-call/40875174#40875174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much around needing to somehow wait for the promise to fulfill before ending the test. There are two main ways of doing it from your code that I can see.

1. independently test that `onClick` and your promise methods. So check that `onClick` calls the correct function, but spying on `setTextWithPromise`, triggering a click and asserting that `setTextWithPromise` was called. Then you can also get the component instance and call that method which returns the promise you can attach a handler and assert it did the right thing.
2. expose a callback prop that you can pass in that is called when the promise resolves.

Answer (score 67):

**Updated answer:** using `async` / `await` leads to cleaner code. Old code below.

I've successfully solved this problem by combining the following elements:

- Mock out the promise and make it resolve immediately
- Make the test asynchronous by marking the test function `async`
- After simulating the click, wait until the next [macrotask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915634/difference-between-microtask-and-macrotask-within-an-event-loop-context) to give the promise time to resolve

In your example, that might look like this:

```
// Mock the promise we're testing
global.doSomethingWithAPromise = () => Promise.resolve();

// Note that our test is an async function
it('displays the promise text after click of the button', async () => {
    wrapper.find('#promiseBtn').simulate('click');
    await tick();
    expect(wrapper.find('#promiseText').text()).toEqual('there is text!');
});

// Helper function returns a promise that resolves after all other promise mocks,
// even if they are chained like Promise.resolve().then(...)
// Technically: this is designed to resolve on the next macrotask
function tick() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 0);
  })
}
```

Enzyme's `update()` is neither sufficient nor needed when using this method, because Promises never resolve in the same tick they are created -- by design. For a very detailed explanation of what is going on here, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202658/why-does-my-test-finish-before-my-enzyme-simulated-event-synchronous-event-han).

**Original answer:** same logic but slightly less pretty. Use Node's [`setImmediate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick) to defer the test until the next tick, which is when the promise will resolve. Then call Jest's [`done`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html) to finish the test asynchronously.

```
global.doSomethingWithAPromise = () => Promise.resolve({});

it('displays the promise text after click of the button', (done) => {
    wrapper.find('#promiseBtn').simulate('click');

  setImmediate( () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('#promiseText').text()).toEqual('there is text!');
    done();
  })
});
```

This isn't as nice because you'll get big nested callbacks if you have to wait for more than one promise.

Comment: BINGO! `setImmediate` was what I needed to use in my callback function which was being triggered by way of one of my component's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods.

Comment: I had a similar problem but I solved it with `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 0)` instead. For some reason `setImmediate` made the tests fail in a way that even the `yarn test` command exited abruptly.

Comment: thank you for this! I called `done()` outside of my setImmediate, but this combination works & prevents test suite from hanging.

Comment: The solution looks promising but in my case setImmediate does not have any effect. The promise is simply ignored and its consequences are not waited on. Do I need to mock the Promise I want to wait on or is there also a way to simply wait on the internally used promises in general?

Comment: `setImmediate()` won't work unless the promise is resolved right away. So you probably want to mock it.

Comment: For those who have multiple promises to be resolved before assertions: the `tick()` helper function along with async test is cleaner and much more readable than nested blocks. One just has to use several `await tick()` calls (as many as there are promises to resolve) and it will work like a charm.
Example use case: when using Promise.all with multiple promises in an array, you will have to use 2 tick calls before your assertions.