# Why does my test finish before my (enzyme simulated event) synchronous event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, jsdom

I have a mocha based test which finishes before my onChange handler in a jsdom based enzyme test of my React component, despite that handler being synchronous using babel+ES2017. If I do a `setTimeout()` of *1ms* to put my `expect()` calls in; the test *passes*.

Just wondering where the break down is? I'm sure there is some simple concept here I'm not considering. I'm thinking jsdom or enzyme does not wait around for the event handler to finish? A problem compounded by the length of time mocking `fetch()` with `fetch-mock` is taking (because it is asynchronous normally).

Is it resolvable without `setTimeout()`, `sinon` or `lolex`, and if not; is it possible with `simon` / `lolex`?

Tomorrow I expect I'll refactor it to avoid mocking fetch() in the tests.

**Test output**

```
</div>
    1) flashes a nice message upon success
Success now!!
End of function now. 


10 passing (4s)
1 failing

 1) <Signup /> flashes a nice message upon success:
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (root, unrendered, ...) } to have a length of 1 but got 0
  at test/integration/jsx/components/signup.test.js:38:54
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

**Bootstrap**

```
require('babel-register')();
require('babel-polyfill');
```

...

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.FormData = document.defaultView.FormData;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

documentRef = document;
```

**Test**

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Signup from '../../../../assets/js/components/signup.jsx';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
```

...

```
it("flashes a nice message upon success", function(){
  fetchMock.mock("*", {body: {}});
  const wrapper = shallow(<Signup />);

  wrapper.find('#email').simulate('change', {target: {id: 'email', value: validUser.email}});

  const signupEvent = {preventDefault: sinon.spy()};

  wrapper.find('#signupForm').simulate('submit', signupEvent);
  wrapper.update();

  console.log(wrapper.debug());
  expect(signupEvent.preventDefault.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  expect(wrapper.find('.alert-success')).to.have.length(1);
  expect(wrapper.find('.alert-success').text()).to.contain('Your sign up was successful!');

  fetchMock.restore();
});
```

**Component**

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ type: 'info', message: 'Sending...', shouldValidateForm: true });
  let form = new FormData(this.form);
  let response;
  let responseJson = {};
  try {
    response = await fetch("/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      body: form
    });
    responseJson = await response.json();
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error("There was a non networking error. ");
    }
    this.setState({ type: 'success', message: 'Your sign up was successful!' });
    console.log("Success now!!");
  } catch(err) {
    this.setState({ type: 'danger', message: "There was a technical problem. "});
  }
  console.log("End of function now. ");
}
```

...

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref={(form) => {this.form = form;} } id="signupForm">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first answer focussed on the asynchronous nature of `simulate`, but from comments it became clear enzyme's implementation of that method [is not asynchronous](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md) as it just calls the click handler synchronously. So this is a rewrite of my answer, focussing on the other causes for asynchronous behaviour.

This test:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.alert-success')).to.have.length(1);
```

... fails because at that time the following line has not yet been executed:

```
this.setState({ type: 'success', message: 'Your sign up was successful!' });
```

I assume here that this `setState` call will add the `alert-success` class to the message element.

To see why this state has not yet been set, consider the execution flow:

```
wrapper.find('#signupForm').simulate('submit', signupEvent);
```

This will trigger what is specified in the `onsubmit` attribute of the form:

```
onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
```

So `handleSubmit` is called. Then a state is set:

```
this.setState({ type: 'info', message: 'Sending...', shouldValidateForm: true });
```

... but this is not the state you need: it does not add the `alert-success` class. Then an Ajax call is made:

```
response = await fetch("/signup", {
    method: "POST",
    body: form
});
```

`fetch` returns a promise, and `await` will pause the execution of the function until that promise is resolved. In the mean time, execution continues with any code that is to be executed *following* the call to `handleSubmit`. In this case that means your test continues, and eventually executes:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.alert-success')).to.have.length(1);
```

...which fails. The event signalling that the pending Ajax request has a response might have arrived on the event queue, but it will only be processed after the currently executing code has finished. So *after* the test has failed, the promise, that was returned by `fetch`, gets resolved. This is because the `fetch`'s internal implementation has a callback notifying that the response has arrived, and thus it resolves the promise. This makes the function `handleSubmit` "wake up", as the `await` now unblocks the execution.

There is a second `await` for getting the JSON, which again will introduce a event queue cycle. Eventually (pun not intended), the code will resume and execute the state the test was looking for:

```
this.setState({ type: 'success', message: 'Your sign up was successful!' });
```

So... for the test to succeed, it must have an asynchronous callback implemented that waits long enough for the Ajax call to get a response.

This can be done with `setTimeout(done, ms)`, where `ms` should be a number of milliseconds that is great enough to ensure the Ajax response has become available.

Comment: I guess why this wasn't obvious to me, is that all the input change events prior to the form submit were successfully rendered in time. So it sounds like the critical mass of work just hits a point where it finishes 'after' the test then?

Comment: Indeed, "asynchronous" here means that the event is put in the event queue, and so it does not get processed before the currently running code (your test) finishes to completion (i.e. JS call-stack is empty). The only way to get something done after the event (in the event queue) is processed, is to also put something in that queue. This is what `setTimeout` does.

Comment: Perhaps enzyme works differently. `simulate()` appears to be synchronous or reliable to me. I setState (via an event handler) 10000 times and a different state once at the end. That state was rendered ok without the use of `setTimeout()`. But as soon as the event handler has something asynchronous (the mocked `fetch()` in my case), it renders on the next loop. 

I'll answer my own post with an example component + test which seems to illustrate this to me. Unless you disagree or have something further to add?

Comment: Please go ahead. From the article I quoted, I had understood `simulate` is asynchronous, but apparently you have a different behaviour for it.

Comment: In fact, I will rewrite my answer also.

Comment: I have submitted mine.

Comment: OK, I have also updated mine. It shows why the submit handler sets the success status asynchronously.

Comment: I might just say that regardless of whether I use a regular promise or await in the component, using `setImmediate()` makes the original test pass. Does this contradict your statement that the 2nd await creates a new event/loop cycle? Perhaps the json promise specifically is synchronous.

Comment: Promises are never synchronous (by specification), even if the value they expose is immediately available. Anyway the first promise (fetch) is already responsible for the asynchronous nature, so the JSON promise does not really influence that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that unlike `ReactTestUtils` (which @trincot's answer is based on), *enzyme's* `simulate()` is in fact *synchronous*. However my mocked call to `fetch()` was *asynchronous* and the promises were resolving on the next event loop. Wrapping the expectations or assertions in a `setTimeout(()=>done(), 0)` should suffice and perhaps is more reliable than `setImmediate()` which seemed to have a higher priority than `setTimeout()` to me (even though they are both probably executing on the same event loop).

Here is a component and test I wrote to demonstrate.

**The Test Output**

```
<Example />
updated asynchronously
onChangeError ran. 
SUCCESS SOON: Taking a break...
Setting delayed success. 
      ✓ has a rendered success message on the next event loop 
    updated synchronously
onChangeError ran. 
Setting success. 
      ✓ has a rendered success message on this loop
onChangeError ran. 
onChangeError ran. 
onChangeError ran.  
...
onChangeError ran. 
onChangeError ran. 
onChangeError ran. 
Setting success. 
      ✓ has a rendered success message on this loop despite a large simulation workload (2545ms)

   3 passing (6s)
```

**The Component**

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onChangeError = this.onChangeError.bind(this);
    this.onChangeSuccess = this.onChangeSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDelayedSuccess = this.onChangeDelayedSuccess.bind(this);
    this.state = { message: "Initial message. " };
  }
  onChangeError(e){
    console.log("onChangeError ran. ");
    this.setState({message: "Error: There was an error. "})
  }
  onChangeSuccess(e) {
    console.log("Setting success. ");
    this.setState({message: "The thing was a success!"});
  };
  onChangeDelayedSuccess(e){
    console.log('SUCCESS SOON: Taking a break...');
    setTimeout(() =>{
      console.log("Setting delayed success. ");
      this.setState({message: "The thing was a success!"});
    }, 0);
  }
  render(){
    return(
     <div>
       <p>{ this.state.message}</p>
       <input type="text" id="forceError" onChange={this.onChangeError} />
       <input type="text" id="forceSuccess" onChange={this.onChangeSuccess} />
       <input type="text" id="forceDelayedSuccess" onChange={this.onChangeDelayedSuccess} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**The Test**

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Example from '../../../../assets/js/components/example.jsx';

describe("<Example />", function() {
  describe("updated asynchronously", function() {
    it("has a rendered success message on the next event loop ", function(done) {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Example />);
      wrapper.find('#forceError').simulate('change', {target: {value: ""}});
      wrapper.find('#forceDelayedSuccess').simulate('change', {target: {value: ""}});

      setTimeout(function(){
        expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.contain('The thing was a success!');
        done();
      }, 0);
    });
  });
  describe("updated synchronously", function(){
    it("has a rendered success message on this loop", function(done) {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Example />);
      wrapper.find('#forceError').simulate('change', {target: {value: ""}});
      wrapper.find('#forceSuccess').simulate('change', {target: {value: ""}});

      expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.contain('The thing was a success!');
      done();
    });
    it("has a rendered success message on this loop despite a large simulation workload", function(done) {
      this.timeout(100000);
      const wrapper = shallow(<Example />);
      for(var i=1; i<=10000;i++){
        wrapper.find('#forceError').simulate('change', {target: {value: ""}});
      }
      wrapper.find('#forceSuccess').simulate('change', {target: {value: ""}});

      expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.contain('The thing was a success!');
      done();
    });
  });
 });
```