# sinon spy is not called in a stub with async function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, sinon, enzyme

Using `sinon` and `enzyme` I wanna test the following component:

```
// Apple.js
class Apple extends Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {

    this.props.start();
    Api.get()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data); // THIS IS ALWAYS CALLED
        this.props.end();
      });
  }

  render () {
    return (<div></div>);
  }
}
```

If I just check `endApy.called`, it's always false. But wrapping it in a `setTimeout` will make it pass. Why `console.log()` is always called but not the `props.end`? Why `setTimeout` fixes it? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
// Apple.test.js
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Api from './Api';
import Apple from './Apple';


test('should call "end" if Api.get is successfull', t => {
  t.plan(2);
    sinon
        .stub(Api, 'get')
        .returns(Promise.resolve());

    const startSpy = sinon.spy();
    const endApy = sinon.spy();

    mount(<Apple start={ startSpy } end={ endApy } />);

    t.equal(startSpy.called, true);                    // ALWAYS PASSES 
    t.equal(endSpy.called, true);                      // ALWAYS FAILS
    setTimeout(() => t.equal(endApy.called, true));    // ALWAYS PASSES

    Api.get.restore();
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Api.get` is async function and it returns a promise, so to emulate async call in test you need to call `resolves` function not `returns`:

> Causes the stub to return a Promise which resolves to the provided value. When constructing the Promise, sinon uses the Promise.resolve method. You are responsible for providing a polyfill in environments which do not provide Promise.

```
sinon
  .stub(Api, 'get')
  .resolves('ok');
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I fixed the error but I get the same result.

Comment: @norbertpy I've updated the demo, it works there. I understand why it doesn't work in yours, it's because you're testing async function (even when stubbed, it's still async), but don't wait when it will be finished, and checking `spy.called`. You must add `then` callback and assert `spy.called` there. [The fixed demo](https://repl.it/LHde/4)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the `componentDidMount` does not return the promise. So I cannot `then` it. to do the assertion. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

your `console.log(data)` always happens because your Promise does resolve, it just does so after the test has finished, which is why the assertion fails.

By wrapping it in a setTimeout you create another event in the loop, which allows your Promise to resolve before the test finishes, meaning that your assertion will now pass.

This is a fairly common problem when unit testing asynchronous code. Often resolved in wrapping the assertions in `setImmediate` and calling `done` from the callback of `setImmediate`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855794/6024903

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with a spy and using `await Promise.all(spy.returnValues)`worked fine for me. This resolves all the promises and afterwards I can check `spy.called`.