# nodejs function with no body

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

Could you please help me understand below code? I am not able mock method using sinon, what could be wrong with it?

```
const amqplib = require('amqplib');

async function getMessage() {
  const x = amqlib.connect({});
}

// Daemon process
getMessage();

module.exports = {
  getMessage,
};
```

mocking code as:

```
const mqConnMock = sinon.stub(amqplib, 'connect');
```

Comment: An async function returns a resolving promise when there is no method body.

Comment: To be precise ..I am having nodejs code looks like like below.

const amqplib = require('amqplib');

async function getMessage() {
const x = amqlib.connect({});
}

// Daemon process
getMessage();

module.exports = {
getMessage,
}

mocking code as :
const mqConnMock = sinon.stub(amqplib, 'connect');

Mock is not working this case. when i remove line 8 mocking works fine. Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227268/3233827

Comment: No, it didn't. I tired but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.getMessage = async function getMessage() {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: there is another declaration stating that it is a deamon process. I really didnt understand how it works