# Is there an way to wait for event that trigger async function in Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Wizard contains steps, each step has its own validation (sync/async).

for example:

```
<Wizard>
   <Form1 />
   <Form2 />
   <Form3 />
</ Wizard>
```

Each form contains `onContinue` method which validates the form inputs.

```
onContinue = async () => {
    let step = this.steps[this.state.step];
    let validation = await step.validate();
    // check for error and change step number.
    this.changeStep(this.state.step + 1, validation);
};
```

Now I'm trying to test the behavior of the Wizard, by making sure, when clicking onContinue, the step number **Increased** by 1.

```
it('should set the state property "step" to 1 after successfully clicking the continue button', () => {
      const props = {
        id: 'testId',
        children: noErrorChildren
      };
      const wizard= mount(<Wizard {...props} />);
      tree.find('onContinue-button').simulate('click');
      expect(wizard.state().step).toEqual(1);
});
```

After running the test, this error shows up:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  1
Received:
  0
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

the `step` variable is not increased to 1 as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: what is `onContinue` ? is it a `onClick={onContinue}` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing with React's Jest and Enzyme when simulated clicks call a function that calls a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408834/testing-with-reacts-jest-and-enzyme-when-simulated-clicks-call-a-function-that)

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045733/3305456

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii Yes didn't work

Answer (score 5):

The reason why the `step` variable is not increased as expected is because `onContinue` is an `async` function, and your test file did not attempt to wait for a response. Since it is async, and you treated it as a normal function the code continued to execute without waiting for the result.

Try doing this and see if it helps,

In your `it` block you can specify the anonymous function as async, like so:

```
it('should do some stuff...', async () => {
```

and then before the `tree.find` method, add the `await` keyword

```
await tree.find('onContinue-button').simulate('click');
```

Comment: I'm trying to consistently get this to work but the await seems to only work by accident and not by design. There is still a [race condition](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/823#issuecomment-433089259) because simulate doesn't return a promise to actually wait for.