# JavaScript: what type of functions can we create to be executed asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I’m trying to understand how async functions work in JavaScript and how to write them, but it seems to me that the way the language handles async functions is pretty limited, but I can be wrong and, probably, I did not understand it.

I use Visual Studio Code (v. 1.66.2) and Chrome (v 100.0.4896.88) on Windows 10 X64.

Just for experimental purposes, I wrote a simple `heavyLoad()` function that gets a **delay** parameter (that represents a millisecond value) and return `true` after time elapsed:

```
function heavyLoad(delay) {        
    let startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < startTime + delay);
    return true;
}
```

If I write:

```
heavyLoad(5000);
console.log(“Hello”);
```

the `console.log()` function is, obviously, executed after 5 secs, since I have to wait that `heavyLoad()` function ends.

I’m trying to make `heavyLoad()` function as asynchronous so that I can read, in the browser console, **Hello** immediately without waiting for `heavyLoad()` function but I’m not able to do that: I’ve tried to create a **promise** object; I tried to use `async` keyword but nothing works, since I have always to wait that `heavyLoad()` function ends before reading **Hello**.

Is it possible to  make `heavyLoad()` function, essentially as it is, an async one  as I meant?

Comment: You can not make synchronous code like a loop just act like asynchronous code. So you need to use something that is asynchronous. That would be `setTimeout` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: Functions are asynchronous because of the ways they interact with the runtime environment. For plain code as in your example, there's no way to say "please make the following block of code asynchronous".

Comment: You can put your heavy load in a web worker.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39184297/4543207). The second snippet in the question answers your question but there is more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Write your heavy load script in a separate file.

**worker.js**

```
onmessage = function(e) { 
    let startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < startTime + e.data);
    postMessage(true);
}
```

Run that webWorker in the main script file.

**main.js**

```
function heavyLoad(delay) {        
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
        myWorker.postMessage(delay);
        myWorker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            // Log the workers message.
            resolve(e.data);
        }, { once: true });
    })
}

console.log("Starting")
console.time()
heavyLoad(5000).then(data=>{
    console.timeEnd()
})
console.log("end")
```

(Here I'm using console.time method to keep track of the execution time)

Comment: Don't forget to `myWorker.removeEventListener` (or use the [`once` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters)), or this will leak memory

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I've added that.

Answer (score -1):

For timeout there is `setTimeout()` method in javascript.

So you can simply use:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Hello");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: The asker was more interested in how asynchronous functions work in Javascript, rather than just the usage of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code to understand asynchronous working

```
function heavyLoad(delay) {        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         
            setTimeout(()=>{
                resolve(true)
            },delay)
        })
    }

    heavyLoad(5000).then(value=>{
        console.log(value)
    });
    console.log("Hello");
```

It will print `hello` first as you run the code and `true` after 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You have to Use Settimeout function as you want to delay the function as long as you want and also setTimeout will act as asynchronous so you will log out hello immediately

```
function heavyLoad(delay) {        
    setTimeout(() => {
     return true
    },delay);
}

heavyLoad(5000);
console.log("hello");
```