# Wait for a React Component to finish updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

In my tests, I would like to block my main thread until one of my components finishes going through its lifecycle methods, through `componentDidUpdate()`, after I trigger an event that causes it to add children components to itself. How can I do so?

Something like this:

```
describe('my <Component />', () => {
  it('should do what I want when its button is clicked twice', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
    const button = wrapper.find('button');

    // This next line has some side effects that cause <Component /> to add
    // some children components to itself...
    button.simulate('click', mockEvent);

    // ... so I want to wait for those children to completely go through
    // their lifecycle methods ...
    wrapper.instance().askReactToBlockUntilTheComponentIsFinishedUpdating();

    // ... so that I can be sure React is in the state I want it to be in
    // when I further manipulate the <Component />
    button.simulate('click', mockEvent);

    expect(whatIWant()).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

(I want to do this because, right now, I get this warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
```

I believe I'm getting it because my tests cause my component to change its internal state more quickly than React's internal multithreading magic can keep up with, so by the time I i.e. run `button.simulate('click')` the second time, React has instantiated the new child components but hasn't finished mounting them yet. I think that waiting for React to finish updating my Component and its children is the best way to solve that problem.)

Comment: What does the click handler do? All state changes should be synchronous unless you specifically have some timer/async stuff going on.

Comment: DOM updates are also synchronous unless you're doing something weird or are using an exotic flavor of React. I wouldn't be surprised if your `setState` warning is because of your component itself doing a `setState` before mount.

Comment: @Jacob I'm using a third-party library, [React Widgets](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/). My `<Component />` has a React Widgets `DateTimePicker` as one of its children, and the warning appears to be emitted from within the `DateTimePicker`. So unfortunately, I'm exactly sure what changes my event causes and I easily can't try to look into the component to make sure it isn't misbehaving.

Comment: I'm not getting the warning when I run my app in the browser, even when I perform the same actions I simulate in the test, so I believe this problem is specific to how my test environment interacts with my component, not a bug within my component (although I could very well be wrong about that).

Comment: Finally, are you sure that React should synchronously update components? In [a conversation I had in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/settimeout-on-unmounted-component-warning), someone [suggested that's not the case](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=34732693#34732693). And when I surround parts of my code in `settimeout` blocks to give a split-second between the events I simulate, the warning goes away, which really makes it seem to me like React is doing something asynchronously that I want my test to wait for.

Comment: React fiber is an experimental thing they're working on for non-synchronous DOM updates, but that isn't "live" yet. But that's not to say that the component you're testing isn't doing async stuff manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping your `expect()` blocks in a `setImmediate()` block:

```
describe('my <Component />', () => {
  it('should do what I want when its button is clicked twice', (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
    const button = wrapper.find('button');

    button.simulate('click', mockEvent);
    button.simulate('click', mockEvent);

    setImmediate(() => {
      expect(whatIWant()).to.be.true;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Here's what's going on: To handle asynchronicity, Node and most browsers have an event queue behind the scenes. Whenever something, like a Promise or an IO event, needs to run asynchronously, the JS environment adds it to the end of the queue. Then, whenever a synchronous piece of code finishes running, the environment checks the queue, picks whatever is at the front of the queue, and runs that.

`setImmediate()` adds a function to the back of the queue. Once everything that is currently in the queue finishes running, whatever is in the function passed to `setImmediate()` will run. So, whatever React is doing asynchronously, wrapping your `expect()`s inside of a `setImmediate()` will cause your test to wait until React is finished with whatever asynchronous work it does behind the scenes.

Here's a great question with more information about `setImmediate()`: [setImmediate vs. nextTick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349733/setimmediate-vs-nexttick)

Here's the documentation for `setImmediate()` in Node: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args

Comment: I've tried this `setImmediate()` trick in some of my tests, but not in the specific situation described in my question. So there be dragons, and this solution might not work.

Comment: When an assertion (`expect`) fails inside `setImmediate()`, the test terminates with an error instead of marking it as `Fail` and continue. Any work around?

Comment: @VLeong Are you writing your tests as asynchronous tests by using the `done` function in your `it` blocks? See https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code