# How exactly does process.nextTick() work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Official node docs explain the following:

> the nextTickQueue will be processed after the current operation completes, regardless of the current phase of the event loop.

With this in mind, I tested `process.nextTick()` the following way:

```
const heapdump = require('heapdump');

let count = 0;

function snapshot(){
    setTimeout(() => heapdump.writeSnapshot(), 5000)
}

process.nextTick(snapshot);

while(true){
    count++
    console.log(count);
}
```

My intention is to have `process.nextTick(snapshot);` forcefully include the snapshot function into the event loop, calling itself during the infinite `while` loop.

Why does this not happen?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16504980/504930) on how to achieve what you wanted to with this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't happen because node's event loop is single threaded, so the "next tick" will only happen after the infinite `while` is finished processing, which, as you may have guessed, is never.

This happens because node.js can only perform non-blocking I/O operations in this single thread, but synchronous code is executed, well synchronously, and it does block execution of the event loop.

So, in your example, the event loop is blocked waiting for the `while` loop to finish, never reaching the "next tick", or the next phase.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize that synchronous code entirely blocked the event loop. Good to know. Thank you!